# Running batch files - CPLEX Interactive Optimizer

Tags: batch-file, cplex

I am trying to run batch of `.sav` files in CPLEX Interactive Optimizer. IBM provides some documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400068). However, I am facing a few issues:

1. After launching the CPLEX Interactive Optimizer, when drag and drop my batch file (`batch_trial.bat`) from its location (`C:\Users\myname\folder name\`) into the `CPLEX` command prompt (that is, when I hit enter after `CPLEX>C:\Users\myname\folder name\batch_trial.bat`, I get the error that `Command '"C:\Users\myname\folder' does not exist. Type 'help' for a list of commands.` I understand from some forums that this is because of the 'space' in `folder name`, however, the answers in those forums said that using double quotation marks would solve this issue. But I use double quotation marks and I still see the error.
2. I tried entering the batch file contents directly into the CPLEX prompt, like this (this is the contents of `batch_trial.bat`, as suggested by IBM's documentation):

   ```
   CPLEX> @echo off
   for /L %%i in (1,1,2) do (
   move mytest%i.sav mytest.sav
   cplex < mycplexcommands
   move cplex.log mytest%i.log
   )
   ```

   This doesn't work either: For each of `@echo`, `for`, `move`, `cplex` I get similar errors saying that these commands do not exist. I have the two `mytest1.sav`, `mytest2.sav`, and `mycplexcommands.txt` in `C:\Users\myname\folder name\`. The contents of `mycplexcommands.txt` is:

   ```
   read mytest.sav
   optimize
   display solution variables 1-10
   quit
   ```
3. What if I don't have similar names for the `.sav` files? For example, if the files names are `apg.sav` and `hfb.sav`, how do I still get these to be executed by the for loop in the batch file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code from a `.bat` file use `%%i` in the declaration of your `FOR` loop and in the rest of your code.

`move "mytest%%i.sav" "mytest.sav"`

If you run the code block directly in the `shell`then use `%i` in the declaration and in the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will make changes accordingly. Do you have any thoughts on how to address any of the three points above?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are confused about the difference between a batch file (a file with a `.bat` extension) and a command file used by the [CPLEX interactive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/interactiveoptimizercommands.html). A batch file can be run from the [Windows command shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). A CPLEX command file can be run by the interactive when using the redirection operator (`<`, as in your example) or the `-f` option. For example, the `-f` options can be used, like so:

```
cplex.exe -f mycplexcommands.txt
```

For (1) and (2), things are not working because you are trying to run a batch script from within the CPLEX interactive. What may work is if you drag your `mycplexcommands.txt` file into the CPLEX interactive instead.

For (3), see the stackoverflow thread at [How to do a for loop in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192039/how-to-do-a-for-loop-in-windows-command-line) That is, it should start like (this has not been tested):

```
FOR %%i IN (*.sav) DO
```

Lastly, you may be interested in looking at the [Open LP files in CPLEX interactive](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2017/05/24/open-lp-files-cplex-interactive/) article on developerWorks.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Dragging and dropping `mycplexcommands.txt` doesn't work either:`CPLEX>C:\Users\myname\folder name\batch_trial.bat` gives the error `Command '"C:\Users\myname\folder' does not exist. Type 'help' for a list of commands.` Your suggestion to (3) may help once I fix (1) and (2).

Comment: Your comment indicates that you are still trying to read/run a `.bat` file in the CPLEX interactive. You can _not_ do that!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry, there was a mistake in my above comment. I am not able to edit it now. I was trying to run `.txt` file and not a `.bat` file. Running `CPLEX>C:\Users\myname\folder name\mycplexcommands.txt` gave the same error: `Command 'C:\Users\myname\folder' does not exist. Type 'help' for a list of commands.`