# Windows batch FOR loop on range through command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to perform an operation multiple times from a command window. Common sense tells me that a FOR loop should be able to handle this. Sure enough, if I want to execute, say, `myProg.exe`, I can open a command window and use:

```
C:\> FOR %i in (1 2 3) DO myProg.exe
```

Easy.

But what if I want to execute `myProg.exe` 1000 times?  I want to specify a range in the FOR loop, but I'm having trouble seeing how to do this.

Intuitively, it seems like I should be able to do something like one of the following:

```
C:\> FOR %i in (1 to 1000) DO myProg.exe
C:\> FOR %i in (1-1000) DO myProg.exe
```

But, of course, this doesn't work. The FOR loop interprets the list as 3 tokens and 1 token, respectively, so `myProg.exe` is only executed 3 times and 1 time, respectively.

---

**Batch File Solution**

It'd probably be easy to write some sort of batch (.bat) file:

```
SET COUNT=0
:MyLoop
    IF "%COUNT%" == "1000" GOTO EndLoop
    myProg.exe
    SET /A COUNT+=1
    GOTO MyLoop
:EndLoop
```

But isn't there an easy way to do this from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch script loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop)

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't able to find that before posting this - maybe because of the title.  Still, thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the /l tag in your statement to make it loop through a set of numbers.

eg.

```
C:\> FOR /l %i in (1,1,1000) DO myProg.exe
```

This says loop through the range, starting at 1, stepping 1 at a time, until 1000

http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

Answer (score 6):

for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do echo %%i

add another % sign before i to work

Comment: Note that the double % is only required for it to properly work in a batch script. Single % is required for it to work on the command line.