# Windows command line - how to specify range?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-processing

In unix, to copy a set of files, I can do something like:

```
cp /mydocuments/ID00{1..5}F /somewhere
```

what would the equivalent command in windows command line look like? I tried '(1,1,5)' instead of '{1..5}', but that doesn't seem to work.

Edit: 'Windows command line'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOS FOR loop on range through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577492/dos-for-loop-on-range-through-command-line)

Comment: Sorry, yes windows command line (now edited)!

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
for /l %f in (1,1,5) do copy \mydocuments\ID00%fF \somewhere
```

The "/l" is mandatory if you want to use range.

```
for /l %f in (start, step, end) do...
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `/l` (letter L) solved for me. On Windows 10, I executed `for /l %i in (0,5,20) do fsutil file createnew %i.file 50000` and Windows 10 did indeed create files `0.file`, `5.file`, `10.file`, `15.file` and `20.file`, each one of them with a size of 50000 bytes (i.e. 50 thousand bytes = 50 kilobytes).