# Set line as variable then execute script

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm working on a script:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (filenames.txt) do set filename=%%f
echo %filename%
pause
```

The problem is that it only echos the last line in "flienames.txt" and I need it to do them all in order one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) you can read more about loops in batch-file. In your case the code should look like this:

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (filenames.txt) do (
  set filename=%%f
  echo !filename!
)
pause
```