# To create x number of folders and txt files using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I'm new to using batch files and I've been asked to make 3000 folders which include .txt files, all with the name 'Client1', 'Client 2' to 'Client 3000' for the folders and text files but have no idea how to go about this :s

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop for this
take a look at this post:

[Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop)

for a little explanation of who to use such a loop.
Furthermore to create a directory use md with the name you want to use

to create a file a

```
       echo your_text_here > name_of_textfile.txt
```

should do

the windows solution would thus look like

```
     for /l %x in (1, 1, 10) do (
         md client%x
         echo hello > client%x\%x.txt
     )
```

this should get you started

under linux i would use

```
       mkdir client{1..3000}
       touch client*/textfile{1..3000}.txt
```

you can use this with cygwin if you just need to create the directories once...

Comment: you can use `TYPE NUL > client%x\%x.txt` if you don't want all of the text files to say hello and just be blank.

Answer (score 0):

This script creates 5 folders with each folder containing 5 files

```
echo off
SET /a j=0
:floop
IF %j%==5 GOTO END
md client%j%
cd client%j%
SET /a i=0
:loop
IF %i%==5 GOTO FEND
echo This is iteration %i%.
ver | date | time >> file%i%.txt
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP
:fend
SET /a j=%j%+1
cd ..
GOTO FLOOP
:end
echo That’s it!
pause
```

Now if you want to change the total number of folders change

```
IF %j%==5 GOTO END
```

to

```
IF %j%==n GOTO END
```

where n is the number of folders

same way to change number of text files change this line

```
IF %i%==5 GOTO FEND
```

to

```
IF %i%==n GOTO FEND
```

where n is the number of files