# Iteration of batch script based on search string

Tags: windows, batch-file, oracle11g, findstr

I've a `Program2.bat` having Oracle query, which generates a file `log.txt` having content-structure either like:

```
SQL> SELECT SID, SERIAL#, STATUS, USERNAME, LOGON_TIME FROM GV$SESSION WHERE USERNAME = 'DBADMIN' and status in ('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','KILLED') ;

no rows selected

SQL> spool off;
```

OR like:

```
SQL> SELECT SID, SERIAL#, STATUS, USERNAME, LOGON_TIME FROM GV$SESSION WHERE USERNAME = 'DBADMIN' and status in ('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','KILLED') ;


       SID    SERIAL#    STATUS     USERNAME   LOGON_TI                                         
---------- ---------- ----------   ----------  -------------                                          
      2388         54         Active     DBADMIN     28-FEB-14                                      
      2391         37         Active     DBADMIN      17-FEB-14                                         
      2395        111        Inactive   DBADMIN      28-FEB-14                                          
      2780        325        Killed       DBADMIN      26-FEB-14                                       
      2790        111        Killed       DBADMIN      8-FEB-14                               

5 rows selected.

SQL> spool off
```

I'm trying to achieve following things:

- Action-1: Call Program2.bat, which will generate log.txt
- Action-2: Search for the string "no rows selected" in log.txt
- Action-3: If string found then call program1.bat
- Action-4: If string not found then do below:

  1. call program2.bat again and
  2. Do Action-2 again at an interval of 5 mins (means keep searching for string "no rows selected" in log.txt on an interval of 5 mins untill string "no rows selected" got found  ).

     ```
     @echo off
     setlocal

     Call Program2.bat
     >nul findstr /c:"no rows selected" log.txt && (
     call program1.bat 
     ) || (
     call program2.bat
     )
     ```

How Point-2 of Action-4 can be achieved in above script or do we have any other way to achieve all in the easiest way?

Comment: I don't understand the question? Are you using sqlplus?

Comment: [TIMEOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos) and [FOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) is what you need I guess.

Comment: @Alexander..I'm using Oracle Database and I've added more information in question now.