# Batch file to create folders, with an incremental folder name of Name 1, Name 2,

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Does anyone know how I can create a batch file which creates folders in a certain directory with the incremental name of "Problem 1", "Problem 2", ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, like so (if it's in a batch file):

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do mkdir "Problem %%x"
```

Or just simply on the command line:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do mkdir "Problem %x"
```

See here: [Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop)

If you want to do it in Powershell it's a simple one liner like so:

```
for($i = 1; $i -lt 100; $i++) { md "Problem $i" }
```

or

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object{md "Problem $_"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the batch file and ran it. Worked a treat!

Comment: Glad to help, added Powershell to the answer as well.

Comment: If I wanted to start it at say Problem 101 onwards, how would I do this?

Comment: In Powershell you'd change the "$i = 1" to 101 (and the 100 to your end value).  On the batch script, change the "in (1, 1, 100)" to "in (x, 1, y)" where x is your start value and y is your end value (inclusive).

Comment: Used the second PowerShell command to create directories in Azure App Service Kudu. Worked great!