# CMD and for command syntax

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to run a command on multiple files from all subdirectories. The command for one file is like this:

```
AutoReplace ..\src\Path\To\AssemblyInfo.cs copyright year=2016
```

This will process the specified file and update certain data in it. Now I want to make it automatic so that it finds its files on its own. Here's what I tried:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /s /b ..\src\AssemblyInfo.cs') do AutoReplace %~fa copyright year=2016
```

When I type it directly in a CMD window, it works. I can see all commands for the files being printed and the files are updated as expected. But when I save this command in a file like `update_copyright_year.cmd`, it says this when I call it:

> D:\build>update_copyright_year.cmd
> "copyright" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.
>
> D:\build>for /f ~fa copyright year=2016
>
> D:\build>

Some kind of syntax error at the word "copyright" which is just another argument to the program AutoReplace. What's wrong here?

Comment: Use `%%a` when running from batch file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop.

Comment: Great, that's it! Thanks. Pretty inconsistent...