# Variable as placeholder in batch loop script call

Tags: loops, batch-file, winscp

I'd like to execute a script with options in a *go-to-loop* like so:

```or-tag-here
@echo off

rem my Array to loop thru

set Arr[0]=foo
set Arr[1]=bar
set Arr[2]=baz
set Arr[3]=bing
set Arr[4]=bang
```

After @Ken White's comment:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 4) do (
    set VAR=%%Arr[%%x]%%
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /script=C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\%VAR%
    rem works as echo:
    call echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /script=C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\%VAR%
)
```

It *still* keeps returning the following error: `Cannot open file "C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\%Arr[0]%"`

If I do a `call echo ...` it shows the correct path tho...

I tried different things:

- `set VAR=C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\ + %%me%%`
- `set VAR="C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\ + %%me%%"`
- `set VAR=C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\%%me%%`
- `set VAR="C:\Dev\Automated_FTP_Scripts\%%me%%"`
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /script=%%Arr[%%x]%%`

**The question:** How can I pass `all_path` to the `winscp` option `/script`?

One problem is that I don't know how to google that; I always get results on how to pass a parameter to a .bat file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591758/62576 might help with this (including showing a much better way to iterate through a list).

Comment: @KenWhite I'll give it a try... thank you

Comment: @KenWhite Still the same issue

Comment: Try [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: You also need `call` for the `winscp.com` execution, just like you do for `echo`; Anyway, I don't get why you need an interim variable `VAR`. By the way, the `for /L` loop should start at `0`, not at `1`...

Comment: `for /d %%x in (foo, bar, baz, bing, bang) do using delayedexpansion and `%%x` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: So @KenWhite yes naturally the counter should start at 0... ;-) @Klitos Kyriacou `Delayed Expansion` wasn't necessary. The `call` to launch winscp was the only thing missing... thx to all. I'm a bit unsure wheter I should close that question "no longer reproducable"

Comment: The interim variable `VAR`was just for testing