# Streaming python to GRBL

Tags: python, repeat, cnc, g-code

I have found a [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grbl/grbl/master/doc/script/stream.py) to send a g-code to GRBL but, i would like this script to repeat 30 times.
how do i write this into the code?

The code i am trying to repeat is
G91Y-20X15F500
G90Y3.00F250

I have research on while and loops but i do not understand why "print" is used so frequently.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to put your g-code into a file, then pass the filename to the command:

```
$ python stream.py commands.gcode /path/to/serial-device
Initializing grbl...
SND: 1 : G91Y-20X15F500 BUF: 15 REC:
SND: 2 : G90Y3.00F250 BUF: 28 REC:
G-code streaming finished!

WARNING: Wait until grbl completes buffered g-code blocks before exiting.
  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.
```

Not sure about the waiting for buffered blocks to finish running, but to run the script 30 times you'd use a loop, for example in bash:

```
for i in `seq 1 30`; do python stream.py commands.gcode /path/to/serial-device; done
```

You could also do the loop with [Windows batch commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) or another Python script. I'd recommend putting the code you linked to inside of a function to make it easier to call from other Python code.

You'd probably want it to run unattended, so you'd have to remove the `raw_input(...)` line and replace it with either a call to `sleep()` or some additional operations with the serial device to poll whether the script has finished running on the machine.

The `print` statements are used for displaying the current status of the program (when the device is initialized, when a line of code is sent to the device, when it's finished, etc.).