# 7zip creating empty archives with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, archive, 7zip

I want to zip everything in a folder, EVERYTHING, but into individually named archives. For some reason every solution on the internet only zips folders, or fails to work at all.

Currently, I have

```bat
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Which I interpret to mean

- `for` = initiate a loop
- `/d` = I don't know what this means
- `%%X` = I don't know what this means
- `in` = not sure, I think it means current directory
- `(*)` = I don't know what this means
- `do` = execute the next thing in `"`...`"`
- `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"` = the thing I want done.
- `a` = add to archive
- `-m9` = max compression
- `"%%X.zip"` = make it a zip file, though I still don't know what `%%X` is.
- `"%%X\"` = even if I knew what "%%X\" meant I don't know why it's here.

I have figured out replacing `%%X` gives the archive a name, so it seems to copy the name of the thing being targeted.

So if I guess, I think `/d` is "target folders" and `%%X` is the name.

So

```bat
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Says in English as I understand it: for every folder name in the current directory, use 7z to max compress it into a zip of the same name... except I don't know what to replace `/d` with to make it target files instead of folders. And targeting specific extensions would be even better.

I tried googling what does "`/d` in cmd mean," "what does `%%X` mean", etc. I don't seem to be getting correct results in the search, I think I'm being too vague for google.

UPDATE:

```bat
for %%i in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx "%%i.zip" "%%i\*.*"
```

seems to make a zip file NAMED each item in the folder, but does not actually add any files to them. I tried adding `/f`, but it didn't work at all when I did that.

Additionally, the first time I posted this it was closed as a duplicate of [Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop) which has almost nothing to do with my problem. Yes, I have a loop, yes that addresses batch loops, but no, it does not come close to solving my problem since my problem isn't with the loop itself., or if it does I have absolutely no idea why or how. So please, explain it to me. I did see the section where it says `%%X` is the variable, but that just means I suppose X could be anything I want it to be, and since in my update I indicated a secondary issue, I think the problem I'm having is with 7z and not the bat file.

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the output text...

Comment: Or type `help for` and hit enter at that same command prompt. Either of them will work to get you information on `for` and it's use.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` command can be very confusing at first, however there is many videos and sites that show examples of how to use it.
To start with try `for /?` to see the built in help information.

The below code should be what you are after if i understand your requirements correctly.. if not then this should help you understand the principles and adjust for your needs.

```bat
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /A-D /B /ON "C:\Test Folder\"') do (
    echo Processing File: C:\Test Folder\%%a
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx1 -tzip "C:\Test Folder\%%a.zip" "C:\Test Folder\%%a"
    echo.
)
pause
```

---

Now lets go through it line by line...

```bat
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /A-D /B /ON "C:\Test Folder\"') do (
```

`/F` Tells it to work with `files` instead of `directories`(`/D`)

`in (' ')` Contains the command that finds the filenames. Note the `'` marks at each end of the command...they are important.

`%%a` Represents each value of a filename that the `in()` command passes it.

`do ( )` What it should do with each `%%a` value it receives.

---

Now we get to the command that is finding the filenames and passing to the `do ()` section as `%%a`

```bat
('DIR /A-D /B /ON "C:\Test Folder\"')
```

You can find more info on the this by running `dir /?`

`/A-D` Tells it to ignore Directories... only list files.

`/B` Output just the file names and not anything else like sizes or it will confuse the `for` command.

`/ON` Feed the filenames to the `do()` command in alphabetical order

`"C:\Test Folder\"` The folder that contains all the files we want to list/perform actions on. Make sure you include the trailing slash. Also use the `""` marks or it wont work if a folder has a space in its name.

---

Write(echo) to the screen a message showing which file it is about to do.

```bat
echo Processing File: C:\Test Folder\%%a
```

---

You can find more information on how to use the 7zip command line functions at https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm

```bat
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx1 -tzip "C:\Test Folder\%%a.zip" "C:\Test Folder\%%a"
```

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"` Run this program.... and pass it the following information (arguments/switches)

`a` Add files rather than extract, etc.

`-mx1` Use the fastest compression method...but less space efficient.

`-tzip` Use the `ZIP` compression format

`"C:\Test Folder\%%a.zip"` Save the new "zip" file as this.  (`%%a` will be replaced with the name of the current file... aka ChuckNorris.mpg which would end up as ChuckNorris.mpg.zip)

`"C:\Test Folder\%%a"` This is the actual file you want to zip.