# Batch COPY command

Tags: windows

Using a batch file, can I copy a file to another with the same name with an added sequentially increasing number such as COPY FILENAME FILENAM01, next time copying to FILENAM02 or any different identifying name, possible with date and/or time?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy
The first entry when you google "bat copy"

[Batch script loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop)

Time:

```
%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%
```