# merge multiple sql files into single sql file with new line in Windows

Tags: windows, merge, newline

I want to merge multiple sql files into single sql file.
In windows terminal I am using below `type` command which is working fine. But during merge i need to add new line space after every file but dont know how to do it. Is there any option in type command or do i need to use any other command ?

```
type *.sql > TRT.sql
```

Comment: Should use loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko i still dont understand in loop what command i have to use to add new line space after each file merge

Comment: Maybe `echo '' >> TRT.sql` on each iteration?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko can you please tell the complete command which i can test ? sorry i am very much new to this terminal command ..