# C++ Application Built using Visual Studio Fails to execute Sometimes

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.5. on my Windows machine.

I built a basic hello world program using Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>  
int main() {
     std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

It generates a exe file called 'ConsoleApplication4.exe'.

If I run 'ConsoleApplication4.exe' from cmd it will output "Hello World!".

But if I run this in loop like in a batch file:

```
ConsoleApplication4.exe
ConsoleApplication4.exe
ConsoleApplication4.exe
ConsoleApplication4.exe
..
.
.
40 times
```

sometimes it will not give any output.

I have attached op2.txt its output here. It got executed only 39 times. And each time I run the batch file. The number of times it is executes varies.

op2.txt

```
D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!
```

Why is this happening?

Note:

It is a small example of what I am trying to do. Actually I am using Visual Studio to build postgres and getting same kind of issue with the binaries generated from Visual Studio

Comment: Maybe  your antivirus is the problem.

Comment: Maybe you need `std::cout << "Hello World!" <<std::endl;`

Comment: FYI -- A batch file has looping syntax (using `for`), where you don't need to copy and paste `ConsoleApplication4.exe` 40 times.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see

```
D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe

D:\project\basic\ConsoleApplication4\x64\Debug>ConsoleApplication4.exe
Hello World!
```

That sometimes there is no output.  What we can't see is the cause.
I think it is likely that the output occurs, but that the buffer is not written and flushed before the next execution runs, and the console output is lost.

Firstly try a std::flush;

```
#include <iostream>  
int main() {
     std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << std::flush; 
}
```

This ensures that the process has written all data out, before it exits, and we can then identify if it doesn't run, or doesn't output

Comment: with flush, it is working fine.
In C language, fflush(stdout) can be used instead.

But  I have a doubt, In my machine this problem is happening. But I tried the same in other machine but there without flush correct output is coming.
Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: In short it is complicated.  The shell (cmd.exe) starts the process, and also outputs itself.  Sometimes the IO from the child process and the IO from cmd.exe are going to output at the same time, and its exactly whether cmd.exe uses buffered IO, or not which results in the output disappearing.

I think the output always works, but is overwritten by the shell's output.