# What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file with following content:

```
echo %~dp0
CD Arvind
echo %~dp0
```

Even after changing directory value of `%~dp0` is the same.
However, if I run this batch file from CSharp program, the value of `%~dp0` changes after **CD**. It now points to new directory. Following is the code that I use:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(//Dir where batch file resides);
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
Process process = new Process();
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("mybatfile.bat");
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
process.Close();
```

Why is there a difference in output on executing same script by different ways?

Do I miss something here?

Comment: You can replicate the behaviour when you run the batch from `cmd` via `"mybatfile.cmd"` (yes, *with* quotes). That's exactly the invocation you get when running via `Process.Start` as you can verify by `echo`ing `%0` as well.

Comment: Thanks a loy Joey, your suggestions did the trick. It works for me now.

Comment: Well, it was just an observation; I still cannot explain the behaviour :-)

Comment: This is also happening for me. Under certain circumstances (that I haven't completely pinned down), if I launch "xyz.bat" from the commandline, the "%~dp0" value works OK, but if I launch the same bat file via Java ProcessBuilder "%~dp0" gives the CWD. Using "cmd /c xyz.bat" seems to fix it, but why?

Answer (score 16):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19781569/2861476) started the discussion on this point, and some testing was done to determine why. So, after some debugging inside `cmd.exe` ... (this is for a *32 bit Windows XP cmd.exe* but as the behaviour is consistent on newer system versions, probably the same or similar code is used)

Inside Jeb's answer is stated

```
It's a problem with the quotes and %~0.
cmd.exe handles %~0 in a special way
```

and here Jeb is correct.

Inside the current context of the running batch file there is a reference to the current batch file, a "variable" containing the full path and file name of the running batch file.

When a variable is accessed, its value is retrieved from a list of available variables but if the variable requested is `%0`, and some modifier has been requested (`~` is used) then the data in the running batch reference "variable" is used.

But the usage of `~` has another effect in the variables. If the value is quoted, quotes are removed. And here there is a bug in the code. It is coded something like (here simplified assembler to pseudocode)

```
value = varList[varName]
if (value && value[0] == quote ){
    value = unquote(value)
} else if (varName == '0') {
    value = batchFullName
}
```

And yes, this means that when the batch file is quoted, the first part of the `if` is executed and the full reference to the batch file is not used, instead the value retrieved is the string used to reference the batch file when calling it.

What happens then? If when the batch file was called the full path was used, then there will be no problem. But if the full path is not used in the call, any element in the path not present in the batch call needs to be retrieved. This retrieval assumes relative paths.

A simple batch file (`test.cmd`)

```
@echo off
echo %~f0
```

When called using `test` (no extension, no quotes), we obtain `c:\somewhere\test.cmd`

When called using `"test"` (no extension, quotes), we obtain `c:\somewhere\test`

In the first case, without quotes, the correct internal value is used. In the second case, as the call is quoted, the string used to call the batch file (`"test"`) is unquoted and used. As we are requesting a full path, it is considered a relative reference to something called `test`.

This is the why. How to solve?

**From the C# code**

- Don't use quotes : `cmd /c batchfile.cmd`
- If quotes are needed, use the full path in the call to the batch file. That way `%0` contains all the needed information.

**From the batch file**

Batch file can be invoked in any way from any place. The only reliable way to retrieve the information of the current batch file is to use a subroutine. If any modifier (`~`) is used, the `%0` will use the internal "variable" to obtain the data.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getCurrentBatch batch
    echo %batch%

    exit /b

:getCurrentBatch variableName
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    goto :eof
```

This will echo to console the full path to the current batch file independtly of how you call the file, with or without quotes.

**note**: Why does it work? Why the `%~f0` reference inside a subroutine return a different value? The data accessed from inside the subroutine is not the same. When the `call` is executed, a new batch file context is created in memory, and the internal "variable" is used to initialize this context.

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to explain why this behaves so oddly.  A rather technical and long-winded story, I'll try to keep it condense.  Starting point for this problem is:

```
   ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

You'll see that if you omit this statement or assign *true* that it works as you expected.

Windows provides two basic ways to start programs, ShellExecuteEx() and CreateProcess().  The UseShellExecute property selects between those two.  The former is the "smart and friendly" version, it knows a lot about the way the shell works for example.  Which is why you can, say, pass the path to an arbitrary file like "foo.doc".  It knows how to look up the file association for .doc files and find the .exe file that knows how to open foo.doc.

[CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the low-level winapi function, there's very little glue between it and the native kernel function (NtCreateProcess).  Note the first two arguments of the function, `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine`, you can easily match them to the two ProcessStartInfo properties.

What is not so visible that CreateProcess() provides two distinct ways to start a program.  The first one is where you leave lpApplicationName set to an empty string and use lpCommandLine to provide the entire command line.  That makes CreateProcess friendly, it automatically expands the application name to the full path after it has located the executable.  So, for example, "cmd.exe" gets expanded to "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe".  But it does **not** do this when you use the lpApplicationName argument, it passes the string as-is.

This quirk has an effect on programs that depend on the exact way the command line is specified.  Particularly so for C programs, they assume that `argv[0]` contains the path to their executable file.  And it has an effect on `%~dp0`, it too uses that argument.  And flounders in your case since the path it works with is just "mybatfile.bat" instead of, say, "c:\temp\mybatfile.bat".  Which makes it return the current directory instead of "c:\temp".

So what your are **supposed** to do, and this is totally under-documented in the .NET Framework documentation, is that it is now up to you to pass the **full** path name to the file.  So the proper code should look like:

```
   string path = @"c:\temp";   // Dir where batch file resides
   Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
   string batfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "mybatfile.bat");
   ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batfile);
```

And you'll see that `%~dp0` now expands as you expected.  It is using `path` instead of the current directory.

Comment: What is the correct workaround if you don't know the full path (i.e. you want a %PATH% lookup)? Do you need to do a manual %PATH% lookup in C#?

Comment: Erm, yes.  Using cmd.exe /c gets to be pretty attractive of course :)

Answer (score 4):

Joey's suggestion helped.
Just by replacing

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("mybatfile.bat");
```

with

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "mybatfile.bat");
```

did the trick.

Comment: Still, I would love to understand what's going on

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with the quotes and `%~0`.

cmd.exe handles `%~0` in a special way (other than `%~1`).
It checks if `%0` is a relative filename, then it prepend it with the start directory.

If there a file can be found it will use this combination, else it prepends it with the actual directory.
But when the name begins with a quote it seems to fail to remove the quotes, before prepending the directory.

That's the cause why `cmd /c myBatch.bat` works, as then `myBatch.bat` is called without quotes.
You could also start the batch with a full qualified path, then it also works.

Or you save the full path in your batch, before changing the directory.

A small `test.bat` can demonstrate the problems of cmd.exe

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo %~fx0 %~fx1
cd ..
echo %~fx0 %~fx1
```

Call it via (in C:\temp)

```
test test
```

The output should be

```
C:\temp\test.bat C:\temp\test
C:\temp\test.bat C:\test
```

So, `cmd.exe` was able to find `test.bat`, but only for `%~fx0` it will prepend the start directory.

In the case of calling it via

```
"test" "test"
```

It fails with

```
C:\temp\test C:\temp\test
C:\test C:\test
```

`cmd.exe` isn't able to find the batch file even before the directory was changed, it can't expand the name to the full name of `c:\temp\test.bat`

**EDIT: FixIt, retrieve the fullname even when `%~0` has quotes**

There exists a workaround with a function call.

```
@echo off
echo This can be wrong %~f0
call :getCorrectName
exit /b

:getCorrectName
echo Here the value is correct %~f0
exit /b
```

Comment: So it would seem that both C#'s "ProcessStartInfo" and Java's "ProcessBuilder" are adding quotes to the executable name, or the underlying O/S mechanism that they share is doing that. Is that controllable?

Comment: @Rich, there is a bug in the quote management of `cmd`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851883/2861476). Use full paths on the call or add code in the batch file to ensure you get the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Command line interpreter **cmd.exe** has a **bug** in code on getting path of batch file if the batch file was called with double quotes and with a path relative to current working directory.

Create a directory **C:\Temp\TestDir**. Create inside this directory a file with name **PathTest.bat** and copy & paste into this batch file the following code:

```
@echo off
set "StartIn=%CD%"
set "BatchPath=%~dp0"
echo Batch path before changing working directory is: %~dp0
cd ..
echo Batch path after  changing working directory is: %~dp0
echo Saved path after  changing working directory is: %BatchPath%
cd "%StartIn%"
echo Batch path after restoring working directory is: %~dp0
```

Next open a command prompt window and set working directory to **C:\Temp\TestDir** using the command:

```
cd /D C:\Temp\TestDir
```

Now call **Test.bat** in following ways:

1. `PathTest`
2. `PathTest.bat`
3. `.\PathTest`
4. `.\PathTest.bat`
5. `..\TestDir\PathTest`
6. `..\TestDir\PathTest.bat`
7. `\Temp\TestDir\PathTest`
8. `\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat`
9. `C:\Temp\TestDir\PathTest`
10. `C:\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat`

Output is four times **C:\Temp\TestDir\** as expected for all 10 test cases.

The test cases 7 and 8 start the batch file with a path relative to root directory of current drive.

Now let us look on results on doing the same as before, but with using double quotes around batch file name.

1. `"PathTest"`
2. `"PathTest.bat"`
3. `".\PathTest"`
4. `".\PathTest.bat"`
5. `"..\TestDir\PathTest"`
6. `"..\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`
7. `"\Temp\TestDir\PathTest"`
8. `"\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`
9. `"C:\Temp\TestDir\PathTest"`
10. `"C:\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`

Output is four times **C:\Temp\TestDir\** as expected for the test cases 5 to 10.

But for the test cases 1 to 4 the second output line is just **C:\Temp\** instead of **C:\Temp\TestDir\**.

Now use `cd ..` to change working directory to **C:\Temp** and run **PathTest.bat** as follows:

1. `"TestDir\PathTest.bat"`
2. `".\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`
3. `"\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`
4. `"C:\Temp\TestDir\PathTest.bat"`

The result for second output for the test cases 1 and 2 is **C:\TestDir\** which does not exist at all.

Starting the batch file without the double quotes produces for all 4 test cases the right output.

This makes it very clear that the behavior is caused by a bug.

Whenever a batch file is started with double quotes and with a path relative to current working directory on start, `%~dp0` is not reliable on getting the path of batch file when current working directory is changed during batch execution.

This bug is also reported to Microsoft according to [Windows shell bug with how %~dp0 is resolved](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/617705/windows-shell-bug-with-how-dp0-is-resolved).

It is possible to workaround this bug by assigning the path of the batch file immediately to an environment variable as demonstrated with the code above before changing the working directory.

And then reference the value of this variable wherever path of batch file is needed with using double quotes where required. Something like `%BatchPath%` is always better readable as `%~dp0`.

Another workaround is starting the batch file always with full path (and with file extension) on using double quotes as class `Process` does.

Comment: Yes, there is a bug. If interested, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851883/2861476).

Answer (score -3):

Each new line in your batch called by your ProcessStart is independently considered as a new cmd command.

For example, if you give it a try like this:

```
echo %~dp0 && CD Arvind && echo %~dp0
```

It works.

Comment: Not for the reason you think it does. It's just that `%~dp0` gets replaced by the actual values prior to execution of the line, thus the second `echo` already outputs static text before the `cd` even ran.

Comment: @Joey : so the ProcessStart or the double quote execution makes the script to be executed line by line, and not as a whole, thus the replacement of %~dp0 which gives different values in the 2 different cases ?

Comment: Batch files are always executed line by line and they are always executed by a single instance of `cmd`. Your alleged solution is just an artifact of how variable expansion is done.

Comment: @Joey : Ok, no problem about me being wrong, just trying to understand :) so the explanation would be that the variable replacements are done before the execution of the whole script in one case, and only before each line execution on the other case ? I'm currently looking on the internet for a reason about this behaviour, but can't find anything :/