# Rafer to the other batch in the in the same folder win 2008

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I refer to other files in the same folder as the batch script by using this syntax:
  CALL %0..\SecondBatch.cmd and this works with windows 2003 server but is not working with 2008 server. Any ideas are do welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you started the script as Admin (this will change the directory to system32)?Try with:
`"%~dpfs0\SecondBatch.cmd"` Thus you'll call the second .bat using the full path.

Comment: when ran the bat  "CALL %~dpf0\..\SecondBatch.cmd" got this error - is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: try with `call ""%~dpfs0\SecondBatch.cmd""`

Comment: nothing has changed , has not working. I would like to add the the bat files there are in the different sub folders but in the same root  folder.This is the error: E:\Folder 1\ folder 2\>setlocal enableextensions

E:\Folder 1\ folder 2\>CALL "\Folder 1\ folder 2\first.cmd"\..\second.cmd

'"E:\Folder 1\ folder 2\>CALL "\Folder 1\ folder 2\first.cmd"\..\second.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of calling another batch file in the same directory of the running batch should be

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    rem This is first.cmd , Let's call second.cmd

    call "%~dp0\second.cmd"
```

But there could be a problem. If first.cmd has been called with quotes, and inside first.cmd the current drive has been changed, the reference `%~dp0`, that should return the path of the current batch file, [fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783666/2861476).

If this is your case, a construct of this kind can be used

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    rem This is first.cmd , Let's call second.cmd

    call :getScriptPath folder
    call "%folder%\second.cmd"

    exit /b 

:getScriptPath returnVar
    set "%~1=%~dp0"
    goto :EOF
```