# Using CMD to open an .exe file, from the same directory?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

Im trying to make this launcher for my game.
But I can't seem to find anywhere, how to open a file. Without specifying the location.
Like I want it to run a file, from the same folder as the .cmd file is in. (The one I created).
Been searching for ages, without finding out how.

Reasoning: The user is able to change where the game is going to be installed. So I cant specify a location..

Comment: If you are in the same folder, just type in the name of the exe file

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440709/2861476) could help

Answer (score 0):

Simply open Command Prompt. Then Drag and Drop your .exe file to the console. (This will copy the location of the .exe file to the console) Then just press "Enter". Then your .exe file should be running.

References http://www.howtogeek.com/209694/running-an-.exe-file-via-command-prompt/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The argument `%0` of a batch file references the name of that batch file. So to run an exe located in the same folder where your batch file is, use:

```
%~dp0program.exe
```

The `~dp` expands the argument `%0` to a full qualified path name - including a trailing `\` that's why there is no `\` between `%~dp0` and `program.exe`

Details about expanding variables can be found by typing `help for` on the commandline

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, it was just me being foolish.
Forgot that I could just type in the name of the file.
Instead of doing something big out of it.
Thanks @ByteHamster for refreshing my memory :)

> "Quote" ByteHamster: If you are in the same folder, just type in the name of the exe file.