# Mimic drag-and-drop from the Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, bluetooth

In Windows, you can initiate a Bluetooth transfer of a file by right clicking the file and choosing **Send to** > **Bluetooth device**. The Bluetooth File Transfer box appears, after which you select what device to send to. I have found that I can achieve the same effect by dragging-and-dropping the file that you want to send onto `C:\Windows\system32\fsquirt.exe`.

To figure out how Windows passes files to programs when you use **Send to** or drag-and-drop, I wrote the following Python script and placed a shortcut to it in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`. The shortcut's Start In directory is the `.py` file's containing directory. (I am using Python 3.6.)

```
#!python3
import os, sys
print(os.getcwd())
print(sys.argv)
input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

When I drag-and-drop a file onto the shortcut or the script itself and when I right-click a file and choose **Send to** > the new shortcut, the same thing happens in all three cases: on the first line, Python prints out the containing directory of the `.py` file, and on the second line, Python prints out a `repr` of a list containing two elements: the absolute path to the `.py` file and the absolute path of the file that I chose.

I wrote the following batch file for testing:

```
cd C:\folder\of\py\file\
C:\folder\of\py\file\argv_dump.py "C:\path\to\a\file.txt"
```

When I run this batch file, either from the command prompt or by double-clicking it in Windows Explorer, I get the same output from before. on the first line, Python prints out the containing directory of the `.py` file, and on the second line, Python prints out a `repr` of a list containing two elements: the absolute path to the `.py` file and `C:\path\to\a\file.txt`.

Now, I am trying to initiate a Bluetooth transfer on Windows 10 from a script. I have written a three-line batch file for testing:

```
cd C:\Windows\system32\
C:\Windows\system32\fsquirt.exe "C:\path\to\a\file.txt"
pause
```

This does not appear to send `"C:\path\to\a\file.txt"` to `fsquirt.exe`. The Bluetooth File Transfer dialog box appears, but it still asks me to choose what file I want to send. Running these commands in a command prompt window yields the same result.

How does `fsquirt.exe` know the difference between when I drag-and-drop or use **Send to** and when I manually pass it an absolute file path from a batch file or the command prompt? How can I get `fsquirt.exe` to notice the file path that I am giving it?

I did look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963931/dos-batch-different-behaviour-between-command-line-and-drag-and-drop), which suggested checking the current working directory of the batch file. Wouldn't `cd`ing inside my batch file take care of that, though?

Comment: The `CD` command is also dependent on if you are changing to a different drive letter as well.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks, I forgot to mention. All the files that I am working with are on the C: drive.

Comment: I can't believe there is no satisfactory answer to this question yet! I was trying to do the same thing, also with fsquirt.exe (what a name). There should be a reliable automated way to reproduce drag-and-drop behavior via the command line. It would help if Microsoft had a more versatile and better-documented Bluetooth command-line tool. chris g suggests an alternate, but now it hasn't been updated in over a decade. Automating via code looks [complicated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/531675/can-i-programmatically-do-drag-and-drop-from-my-lo), and macros would be clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have used the [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/) via Bluetooth Installer.  They allowed me to automate a Bluetooth workflow via the Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer, but note that it may be easier in some cases to use a macro to target the "Send To" menu in Explorer.  That includes "Bluetooth device" and items can be added to it.

For example I used [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to save the clipboard to a file and then used [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) to initiate a Bluetooth send.

It's not an elegant enough solution to reproduce in detail, but none of this requires say knowing where the mouse cursor is.  You can select a file in Explorer by sending its name to the active window, and you can get the context menu with Shift-F10.  (Send To is then option N.)

So in the absence of a tool to mimic drag-and-drop, this is at least a quick and dirty way that is somewhat reproducible.

p.s. "Send To" [menu items](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-customize-the-send-to-menu-in-windows) are in [user directory]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo or can be accessed by [running](https://www.howtogeek.com/165912/how-to-send-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-to-a-text-file-via-the-send-to-menu/) (Win+R) "shell:sendto".