# Why I need to mention an absolute address in my batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a .bat file which is my .jar file launcher. The .jar file is a native application that talks with a Chrome extension. I have the following .bat file:

```
@echo off
rem set JARFILE = %CD%\MyNativeApp.jar
java -jar C:\Users\reza.ahmadi\workspace\SimpleNativeApp\bin\MyNativeApp.jar
pause
```

The .jar and the .bat files are in the same folder (along with my manifest). It works well.

**My problem:** It does not work if I replace that path there with just the file name, meaning:

```
java -jar MyNativeApp.jar
```

does not work for me. I am working with a Win 8 machine.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your native host manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically substitute the path by getting it from the currently executing batch file (`%~dp0`):

```
java -jar "%~dp0MyNativeApp.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the jar file is in the same folder that the batch file, you can use

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("%~dp0\MyNativeApp.jar") do set "JARFILE=%%~fa"
    java -jar "%JARFILE%"

    pause
```

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25440709/2861476) more information on how to retrieve the current active folder or the folder where the batch file is stored