# How to get name off current directory

Tags: batch-file

I have been wanting my script to find a folder that starts with the string "onedrive...".
My code looks like this,

```
@echo off

set path="C:\Users\%USERNAME%"

if exist %path% (
cd "%path%\onedrive*"
echo %cd%
cd
)
pause
```

and the output I get is,

```
C:\Users\310176421\Backupscript\source
C:\Users\310176421\OneDrive for Business
```

where the first one is my .bat file directory and the second one is the line i want to make into a variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440709/2861476) could help

Answer (score 1):

Oh man don't do this, you are overwriting the system PATH. You have to use another name for that variable. And also you have to set it as local.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

REM blah blah
set _my_custom_path=....

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple batch code which searches in profile directory of current user for a directory starting with string `OneDrive` and assigns the full path of first found folder without quotes to an environment variable output next before exiting batch.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /S "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "OneDriveFolder=%%~I"
    goto FoundFolder
)
echo Could not find a folder OneDrive.
goto :EOF

:FoundFolder
echo Found folder: %OneDriveFolder%
set "OneDriveFolder="
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`

Note 1: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` is not always equal `%USERPROFILE%` as the profile directory can be also on another drive than drive `C:` and `Users` is just the **default** parent directory for the user profiles on Windows Vista and later.

Note 2: `2^>nul` redirects error message output by command **DIR** to `stdout` to device `nul` which means suppressing the error message in case of no directory starting with `OneDrive` is found case-insensitive. `^` escapes redirection operator `>` for command **FOR** to get `2>nul` applied on command **DIR**.