# How to get the path in which my .bat file is saved?

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

Suppose i have a .bat file saved in a folder .
 When my .bat file runs i need to get the path in which this .bat file is saved . I tried Google it but could not find the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work) which is second on [batch-file votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file?sort=votes&pageSize=30) list. Not so famous is [In Batch file ~dp0 changes on changing directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%~dp0` will give you teh path to the bat file.

If you also need the whole path including the name of the bat file itself use `%~0`.

Comment: Do i have to set it in a variable

Comment: No. %~dp0 is always available in any bat file. Don't set it, just use it! :)

Comment: Please can you give an example.

Comment: Say your bat file is in C:\TEST\BATFOLDER\BatFile.bat. Put the line `@ECHO %~dp0` into your bat and it will print `C:\TEST\BATFOLDER\\`.

Comment: can i get it into a variable ?

Comment: Sure. `Set MyVar=%~dp0` will work. Afterwards you can access it with `%MyVar%`. But why would you put it into a variable if you can always access it with `%~dp0` instead? However, it is possible.

Comment: Or you can use
FOR /F %%a IN ('CD') DO SET BATPATH=%%a