# Behavior of %~dp0 on Windows 2008 Server when used from Java

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-server-2008

> Issue Environment  : Windows Server 2008 R2 Build 7601

I have a batch file `SomeBatchFile.bat` which uses `%~dp0` to get the script location. But when it's executed on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Build 7601` from a java program, its showing a buggy behavior.

Here is the behavior,

1) When executed like this

`Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\full\\path\\SomeBatchFile.bat");`

Keeping the `SomeBatchFile.bat` file in `C:\full\path` (essentially giving the actual full path), its returning the expected result `c:\full\path\`

2) But when executed like this

`Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("SomeBatchFile.bat");`

Keeping the `SomeBatchFile.bat` file in `C:\Windows` (essentially a location that is a part of environment variable `PATH`).This returns a wrong value instead of the `BAT script location`, its returning the `java program location` from where this script is called.

**This is the script file I am using,**

```
REM Just prints the script location to a file

set MY_HOME=%~dp0
echo %MY_HOME% >> test_out.txt

REM And some other business logic here ...
```

> On Windows Server 2003, this is working absolutely fine.

Any idea why this happens like this ? Is this Java/Windows Bug ? And how to resolve this ?

Comment: Pass the correct path as the first parameter?

Comment: The location of the file is not known in advance, the users keeps the script in any location which is a part of the PATH variable and executes the java program. This script picks the location of the script and do some activities. So I wanted to get the location of the script using %~dp0, which is failing on Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Could you include the batch code that is retrieving the path?

Comment: @MC ND - Script file content has been added to the question.

Comment: Silly question, but I have to ask: are you sure you don't have a copy of `SomeBatchFile.bat` in the folder containing the java program location?

Comment: @MC ND - Yes, Java program and script are in different locations.

Comment: @MC ND - Basically the script is kept in a location which is a part of PATH environment variable.

Comment: @k0der, yes it was clear, thank you. I made the question because if the batch file is present in the *"current active folder"*, as it is implicitly included in the path, you end with a call to the wrong batch file. Before trying to search for bugs it is better to discard usual problems.

Comment: Does %dp0 contain a space character?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to launch script in a relative path, you should also give a try for these  syntaxes:

`Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".\\SomeBatchFile.bat");`
or
`Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".\SomeBatchFile.bat");`
or
`Process proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./SomeBatchFile.bat");`

One of the three should work.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to replicate your problem, and the only way I get to do it is if the batch file is executed quoted, that is, if when the java program invokes the `cmd` instance to handle the batch file execution, the batch file name is `"SomeBatchFile.bat"`. You can try to execute your batch file from command line calling it with quotes to see the problem.

That is, a simple batch file as

```
@echo %~dp0
```

placed somewhere in the path (by example, `c:\windows\test.bat`), when called from command line, from any folder, without including the path to it, without quotes (just type `test.bat`), you will retrieve the correct folder. But, if the same test is done calling the file as `"test.bat"` you will retrieve the current folder

```
D:\>type c:\windows\test.bat
@echo %~dp0
D:\>
D:\>test.bat
C:\Windows\

D:\>"test.bat"
D:\

D:\>cd temp

D:\temp>test.bat
C:\Windows\

D:\temp>"test.bat"
D:\temp\
```

I don't have access to neither 2003 not 2008 to check, but *"probably"* the configuration on batch file invocation was changed.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26851883/2861476) (in this case the problem raised from c# and the reference is to the full batch file name, but it is the same problem) you will find **why** this happens.

If the batch file name does not contain spaces or special characters you can simply use something like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c SomeBatchFile.bat")
```

Or, if you can not avoid the quotes in the file name, you can change the batch file to use a subroutine to obtain the required information

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getBatchFolder MY_HOME
    echo %MY_HOME%

    goto :eof

:getBatchFolder returnVar
    set "%~1=%~dp0"
    goto :eof
```