# how to get current directory name while the batch file is called from sub folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know I can use the following code to get the current directory name.

```
for %%* in (.) do echo %%~nx*
```

But that won't work if I have this setup.

```
folderA
    a.bat
    folderB
        b.bat
```

Inside `b.bat`, I have:

```
%~dp0..\a.bat
```

in `a.bat`, I have:

```
for %%* in (.) do echo %%~nx*
```

But the output is `folderB` probably because when `b.bat` is executing, it's executing in the sub folder's context. But I want `a.bat` to output its own directory name which is `folderA`.

How to do that?

Comment: I found better answers for me in https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `a.bat`, use

```
for /f %%q in ("%~dp0.") do echo %%~nxq
```

Comment: btw - with your structure description, you are executing `a.bat` from `b.bat`, so there is no return from `a.bt` to `b.bat`. If you were `call`ing `a.bat` as per your description, you'd need to `call %~dp0..\a.bat` (and you omitted the `~` from your posting.)

Answer (score 2):

There is the environment variable `CD` which always has the path of current directory. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` to get displayed on several pages the help of this command listing at end also the **dynamic** environment variables like `CD`, `DATE` or `TIME` which can't be seen on running just `set` which outputs all currently defined static environment variables.

The current directory can be equal the directory of the started batch file which is usually the case on double clicking on a batch file.

But the current directory can be also any other directory different to directory of the batch file. For example the current directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32` on running a batch file as administrator or as scheduled task with system account or `%SystemRoot%` on double clicking on a batch file on a network resource accessed using a UNC path.

Let us assume there is `C:\folderA\a.bat` with the command lines:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
echo/
echo Current directory is:  %CD%
echo Directory of %~nx0 is: %~dp0
```

And there is `C:\folderA\folderB\b.bat` with the command lines:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
echo/
echo Current directory is:  %CD%
echo Directory of %~nx0 is: %~dp0
echo/
call "%~dp0..\a.bat"
echo/
echo Running again %~nx0
echo/
echo Current directory is:  %CD%
echo Directory of %~nx0 is: %~dp0
echo/
for /F %%I in ("%~dp0..\") do echo Batch parent directory is:   %%~dpI
for /F %%I in ("%CD%\..\") do echo Current parent directory is: %%~dpI
```

Double clicking on batch file `C:\folderA\folderB\b.bat` results in output:

```
Running b.bat

Current directory is:  C:\folderA\folderB
Directory of b.bat is: C:\folderA\folderB\

Running a.bat

Current directory is:  C:\folderA\folderB
Directory of a.bat is: C:\folderA\

Running again b.bat

Current directory is:  C:\folderA\folderB
Directory of b.bat is: C:\folderA\folderB\

Batch parent directory is:   C:\folderA\
Current parent directory is: C:\folderA\
```

Removing the command `call` in line 7 of `b.bat` and running again `b.bat` results in output:

```
Running b.bat

Current directory is:  C:\folderA\folderB
Directory of b.bat is: C:\folderA\folderB\

Running a.bat

Current directory is:  C:\folderA\folderB
Directory of a.bat is: C:\folderA\
```

There is no return to `b.bat` on reaching end of `a.bat` without using `call`.

Next let us look on output on running `b.bat` having again `call` on line 7 from `C:\Windows\System32` with the command line `C:\folderA\folderB\b.bat`:

```
Running b.bat

Current directory is:  C:\Windows\system32
Directory of b.bat is: C:\folderA\folderB\

Running a.bat

Current directory is:  C:\Windows\system32
Directory of a.bat is: C:\folderA\

Running again b.bat

Current directory is:  C:\Windows\system32
Directory of b.bat is: C:\folderA\folderB\

Batch parent directory is:   C:\folderA\
Current parent directory is: C:\Windows\
```

**ATTENTION:**

Path of current directory hold by environment variable `CD` is without backslash at end with one exception: the current directory is the root directory of a drive. In this case `CD` is for example `C:\` instead of just `C:`.

When working with `%~dp0` please take into account:
[What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)