# Start command does not allow the script to fully close until secondary script closes

Tags: batch-file, locking

I've got a batch script `start.bat` that creates a locked `.lock` file (basically, to verify if the script is running, by attempting to delete it) and starts a bunch of secondary looping batch scripts (they keep on running after `start.bat` is closed). The problem is when `start.bat` is closed the locked file remains locked, until ALL of the secondary scripts are closed.

**Question:** Are there any alternative methods to run secondary batch scripts without locking up the primary script until secondary ones are finished?

I feel like most of this code is irrelevant, but included it in case somebody wants to test it.

```
@echo off
set "started="
<nul >"%~nx0.lock" set /p ".=." ::Rewrite lock file with a single dot
2>nul (
  9>>"%~f0.lock" (
  set "started=1"
  call :start
 )
)
@if defined started (
    del "%~f0.lock">nul 2>nul
) else (
    exit //script closes
)
exit /b

:start
//irrelevant loop logic
Start pause.bat //Pause command to keep pause.bat open
//starts other batch files too
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the file may still be in use?

Try:

```
del /F "%~f0.lock">nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are inherited handles. When you start a process with a redirection active, the process inherits the redirection. So, you need to keep the lock but start the processes while not keeping it.

You can try some variation of this

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Check if this is a lock instance
    if "%~1"==".LOCK." goto :eof

    rem Retrieve all the needed data to handle locking
    call :getCurrentFile f0
    for %%a in ("%f0%") do set "lockFile=%%~nxa.lock"
    set "lockID=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"

    rem Try to adquire lock
    set "started="
    2>nul (
        >"%lockFile%" (
            rem We get the lock - start a hidden instance to maintain the lock
            set "started=1"
            start "" /b cmd /k""%f0%" .LOCK. %lockID%"
        )
    )

    rem Check if the lock was sucessful
    if not defined started (
        echo lock failed
        pause
        goto :eof
    )

    rem Launch the child processes, now detached from lock, as this cmd instance
    rem is not holding it. The hidden cmd /k instance holds the lock
    start "" write.exe
    start "" notepad.exe
    start "" /wait winver.exe

    rem Once done, release the locked instance
    >nul 2>nul (
        wmic process where "name='cmd.exe' and commandline like '%%.LOCK. %lockid%%%'" call terminate
    )

    rem And remove the lock file
    del "%lockFile%"

    rem Done
    goto :eof

rem To prevent problems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12141482/2861476        
:getCurrentFile returnVar
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    goto :eof
```

As the hidden `cmd` instance is hosted inside the same console than the current batch file, if you close the console, the lock is released (but the lock file is not deleted)