# Why does command START used in a batch file not start a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command, exit, file-exists

I made a `Main` batch file with the lines below:

```
@echo off
color 1e
title  ------ Just a Test ------
start "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Check.bat"
:START
echo Welcome to the Game!
...
```

And `Check.bat` contains:

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Batch_System\importantFile.dll" goto ERROR
if exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Batch_System\importantFile.dll" goto CONTINUE
:ERROR
cls
echo        ERROR :
echo   Important file not found. please reinstall the program 
pause
exit /b
:CONTINUE
cls
exit /b
```

When I use the command `start`, it starts only a command prompt with the `Check.bat` directory and the main batch file continues executing the game. I want to force close the main batch file if `importantFile.dll` doesn't exist.

Okay, let me explain: When the main batch file is executed and runs the command `start` to start another batch file called `Check.bat`, the file `Check.bat` checks if the file `importantFile.dll` exists, and if not, `Check.bat` displays an error message.

Does anyone know how to write `Check.bat` in a manner that when the .dll file does not exist, force the main batch file to exit?

Comment: The 1st double quoted argument of `start` can be the title. See `start /?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, help on every command can be get by running in a command prompt window the command with `/?` as parameter. `start /?` outputs the help of command **START**. `call /?` outputs the help of command **CALL** usually used to run a batch file from within a batch file. Those two commands can be used to run a batch file as explained in detail in answer on [How to call a batch file that is one level up from the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564)

---

Second, the command line

```
start "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Check.bat"
```

starts a new command process in foreground with a console window with full qualified batch file name as window title displayed in title bar at top of the console window. That is obviously not wanted by you.

---

Third, the Wikipedia article [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) lists the predefined environment variables on Windows and their default values depending on version of Windows.

In general it is better to use `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"` instead of `"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop"`.

There is no `C:\Users` on Windows prior Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 by default at all.

The users profile directory can be on a different drive than drive `C:`.

It is also possible that just the current user's profile directory is not in `C:\Users`, for example on a Windows server on which many users can logon directly and for which the server administrator decided to have the users' profile directories on a different drive than system drive making backup and cleaning operations on server much easier and is also better for security.

Well, it is also possible to have the user's desktop folder not in the user's profile directory. But that is really, really uncommon.

---

Fourth, on shipping a set of batch files, it is recommended to use `%~dp0` to call other batch files from within a batch file because of this string referencing drive and path of argument 0 expands to full path of currently executed batch file.

The batch file path referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash. Therefore concatenate `%~dp0` always without an additional backslash with another batch file name, folder or file name.

See also [What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)

---

Fifth, I suggest following for your two batch files:

**Main.bat:**

```
@echo off
color 1e
title  ------ Just a Test ------
call "%~dp0Check.bat" || color && exit /B
echo Welcome to the Game!
```

**Check.bat:**

```
@echo off
cls
if exist "%~dp0Batch_System\importantFile.dll" exit /B 0
echo   ERROR:
echo   Important file not found. Please reinstall the program.
echo/
pause
exit /B 1
```

The batch file `Check.bat` is exited explicitly on important file existing with returning exit code `0` to the parent batch file `Main.bat`. For that reason Windows command processor continues execution of `Main.bat` on the command line below the command line **calling** the batch file `Check.bat`.

Otherwise `Check.bat` outputs an error message, waits for a pressed key by the user and exits explicitly with non zero exit code `1`. The non zero exit code results in `Main.bat` in executing the next command after `||` which is **COLOR** to restore initial colors and next executing also **EXIT** with option `/B` to exit the execution of `Main.bat`.

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/)
  `exit /B` without an additionally specified exit code is like `goto :EOF`.

The **CALL** command line in `Main.bat` could be also written as:

```
call "%~dp0Check.bat" || ( color & exit /B )
```

And `Main.bat` could be also written as:

```
@echo off
color 1e
title  ------ Just a Test ------
call "%~dp0Check.bat"
if errorlevel 1 (
    color
    goto :EOF
)
echo Welcome to the Game!
```

I do not recommend using in `Main.bat` just **EXIT** instead of `exit /B` or `goto :EOF`. Just **EXIT** would result in exiting the current command process independent on calling hierarchy and independent on how the command process was started: with option `/K` to keep it running to see error messages like on opening a command prompt window and next running a batch file from within command prompt window, or with `/C` to close the command process after application/command/script execution finished like on double clicking on a batch file.

It is advisable to test batch files by running them from within an opened command prompt window instead of double clicking on them to see error messages on syntax errors output by `cmd.exe`. For that reason usage of just **EXIT** is counter-productive for a batch file in development. Run `cmd /?` in a command prompt window for help on Windows command processor itself.

Last but not least see:

- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Answer (score 0):

`start` is asynchronous by default. Use `start /wait` so that `main.bat` can test the exit code of `check.bat`. Make `check.bat` return an appropriate exit code.

For example...

*main.bat*

```
@echo off
start /b /wait check.bat
if not %errorlevel% == 0 exit /b
echo "Welcome to the game!"
...
```

*check.bat*

```
@echo off
if exist "importantfile.dll" exit 0
echo ERROR: Important file not found. Please reinstall the program.
pause
exit 1
```

*notes*

Added `/b` to `start` to avoid opening another window. Change that per your preference.

You could use `call` instead of `start` but `call` gives the called code access to the variables of `main.bat` so encapsulation is improved if you use `start` as you did.

The logic in `check.bat` is simplified above. Once you identify the success path early in the script and exit, the rest of the script can assume the fail path. This saves you a few `if`'s and labels which you might find simplifies writing and reading of similar scripts. Beware of potentially confusing multiple exit points in longer scripts though!

When choosing exit codes, 0 is a common convention for success.

The above code is just one technique - there are several other options (such as `checksomething && dosomethingifok`). Some useful information on return codes, and checking them, can be found in http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html

Comment: Your code is right, but when i open the "check.bat" file it's working fine (Shows to me the error if the file doesn't exist), but when i execute the "main.bat" it's just shows me a CMD console with the directory of the "main.bat" and the color that was in his script (color 1e).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The simple examples above are tested, exactly as they appear (except the "..." at the end of main.bat), by calling "main.bat" from the command line and having "main.bat", "test.bat" and "importantfile.dll" all in the same directory. If you are still seeing colours, are you calling "check.bat" from your original "main.bat"? Do you have the "start /wait /b" changes? If you post your full scripts, I would be happy to test them and help. Also, some great advice in the Mofi's answer although I prefer "start" to "call" for the reasons I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from Mofi. I've my example and exp. on this. To be short, it's about the setting of log date format. You may change the format of time , date and log. you may have the result.

[why-batch-file-run-with-failure-in-windows-server](https://datamansamxiao.wordpress.com/2019/10/05/why-batch-file-run-with-failure-in-windows-server/)