# Incorrect %0 in a .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, path, variable-expansion

I have just noticed a very strange behavior of `%0` in a `.bat` file called via `%PATH%`.

Somewhere in `%PATH%`, *(say, `C:\InPath`)*, create file `xxx.bat` containing:

```
@echo off
echo this = %~f0
```

In a different directory, somewhere not in `%PATH%`, *(e.g. `C:\NotInPath`)*, create file `yyy.bat` containing:

```
@echo off
call "xxx.bat"
```

Change the working directory to anything, (e.g. `C:\SomewhereElse`) and run `yyy.bat`. What I would expect to see is:

```
this = C:\InPath\xxx.bat
```

What I actually get is:

```
this = C:\SomewhereElse\xxx.bat
```

The problem is apparently caused by the quotes in the `call`, because if I change the `call` line in `yyy.bat` to `call xxx.bat`, I get the expected output.

I wonder what could be the reason for this difference in behavior and if there is something I can do to get the correct output even with the quotes - e.g. to facilitate scripts containing a space character. Without executing a new instance of `cmd.exe`, that is *- I need the called script to set some environment values to be read by the caller script*.

Comment: Please try this. in `xxx.bat` `echo local = %~0` and in `yyy.bat` do `echo remote %~0 && call xxx.bat` and show me the output.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: `remote = C:\NotInPath\yyy.bat`, `local = xxx.bat` (no path, %0 in a CALL basically copies the calling string, i.e. when I remove the `.bat` extension from the call, I get `local = xxx`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it with

```
@echo off
echo This can be wrong %~f0

call :fixIt
exit /b

:fixIt
echo FixIt %~f0
```

Link to a good explanation from [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)
[SO:What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26851883/463115)

Comment: Perfect. This solution works. However, I still wonder: Just what is the point of this strange behavior. It seems to be a bug in CMD, but perhaps Microsoft has some reason for it?

Comment: @pepak [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) or I wrote something about `%~0` somewhere on stackoverflow or  dostips.com, my problem is to search for such keywords. Typically Dave wrote better and longer texts than me