# File not found in batch blah.bat

Tags: batch-file

```
:exe
dir /a plugins
cls
set /p load="Which file do you want to load?: "
if exist plugins\%load%.bat goto loadtrue
if not exist plugins\%load%.bat goto loadfail
:loadfail
cls
echo error, file does not exist or you typed the file name wrong, try again
pause
goto exe
:loadtrue
cls
start %load%.bat
pause
goto terminal
```

Comment: Please revisit your question to bring it on topic. You can read [ask] and its associated links, to find out how to do so, and thus improve your chances of receiving help.

Comment: Blah.bat is in the folder plugins

Comment: I have voted to have the above closed. Had you made an attempt at following the advice in my previous comment, or at creating an on topic question, I wouldn't have needed to. Please follow that advice, should you wish to prevent the inevitable closure of your 'question'.

Comment: Hi @LEVI, your paths are not "rooted" meaning that the path is whatever your current working directory is plus the path you are using.  This is most likely what your problem is.  Before the line `if exist plugins\%load%.bat` , try dding a debug statement like `echo looking in %CD%\plugins\%load%.bat for the file.`.  You should immediately see what your problem is.

Comment: One more thing @LEVI... If you run a batch file as an administrator, your working directory will be "%windir%\System32" (a bug imho), otherwise, (by default) it will be the directory the batch is in.  If you add `cd /d %~DP0` to the beginning of your batch file, it will always be in the directory you expect.

Comment: can you rewrite my code to be correct?

Comment: then nothing i will delete my account

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file with comments which are the lines starting with `rem`:

```
@echo off

:UserPrompt
cls
rem Output the names of all batch files in subdirectory plugins in directory
rem of this batch file without file extension and next an empty line.
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0plugins\*.bat" /A /B 2^>nul') do echo %%~nI
echo/

rem Make sure the environment variable Load is not defined by chance
rem for example by a previous execution of this batch file in same
rem Windows command prompt window.
set "Load="

rem Prompt the user for the batch file name to load respectively execute.
set /P "Load=Which file do you want to load? "

rem Has the user input anything at all?
if not defined Load goto UserPrompt

rem Remove all double quotes from input string.
set "Load=%Load:"=%"

rem Is there anything left after removing all double quotes?
if not defined Load goto UserPrompt

rem Is there a batch file with user input name in subdirectory plugins
rem in the directory containing this batch file?
if exist "%~dp0plugins\%Load%.bat" goto StartPlugin

echo/
echo Error: The file name was typed wrong.
echo Please try it again.
echo/
pause
goto UserPrompt

:StartPlugin
cls
rem Start a separate command process for execution of the user selected
rem batch file with window title of console window set to name of batch
rem file and current directory set to subdirectory plugins of the
rem directory containing this batch file.
start "%Load%" /D"%~dp0plugins" ".\%Load%.bat"
pause
goto Terminal

:Terminal
```

I recommend to read in addition to the comments:

- [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/)
- [What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Please note that the directory path referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash and therefore concatenation of this path with a directory or file name should be done without an additional backslash as shown in code above even if it makes the file/folder strings more difficult to read.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`