# How to setup execution/working directory of batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script placed in the `/project/Scripts` directory, but it should be executed in `/project` directory. My task is to design the script in the way it can be executed from `/project/script` directory, but it behaves as it were placed in `/project` directory.

How can I do this magic? I'm not experience in batch magic at all.

The script contains a multiline mvn command and I don't want to pollute the root of the mvn project.

Comment: Would `CD ..` at the beginning of batch file be ok?

Comment: Not really, because you have cd back to the Scripts directory.

Comment: have you looked into `pushd` and `popd`? otherwise you could just set the path as a variable and use it as needed

Comment: 1. The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`. 2. `%~dp0.` points to the parent directory of the script, `%~dp0..` goes one level up. 3. Use `setlocal` at the beginning of the script (and `endlocal` at its end), then you can do [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)`/D "%~dp0.."` to change to the target directory temporarily (alternatively use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html))...

Comment: @SayusiAndo I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands __SETLOCAL__ and __ENDLOCAL__ as well as __PUSHD__ and __POPD__. And read also [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/) which references drive and path of argument 0 which is the drive and path of current executed batch file always ending with a backslash and so `cd /D "%~dp0..\"` changes the current directory to parent directory of the batch file independent on what is the current directory on starting the batch file.

Comment: @SayusiAndo See also [What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/) and read the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file).