# %~dp0 returns incorrect path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have two batch files.

*Bat 1.bat*

```
@echo OFF
setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0"
echo "%~dp0"
cmd /c call "Bat 2.bat"

endlocal
pause
```

*Bat 2.bat*

```
@echo OFF
setlocal

echo "%~dp0"
cd /d "%~dp0..\.."
echo "%~dp0"

endlocal
```

Both files are in the same directory, so I would expect `echo "%~dp0"` to output the same thing every time.

However, after calling `cd /d "%~dp0..\.."`, `echo "%~dp0"` outputs the current directory instead of the directory the batch file is in. Why is the output changing?

---

*Expected*

```
"C:\Testing\DP0 Wrong\"
"C:\Testing\DP0 Wrong\"
"C:\Testing\DP0 Wrong\"
```

*Actual*

```
"C:\Testing\DP0 Wrong\"
"C:\Testing\DP0 Wrong\"
"C:\"
```

Comment: Remove the quotes and it works, in *bat1.bat* `call Bat2.bat`

Comment: @jeb That's strange. Do you know why that is? I will modify the question though as the batch files in my real scenario have spaces in and the names can't be changed

Comment: There is a long analysis about `%~dp0` somewhere at SO or dostips.com (I guess from dbenham, Aacini or perhaps from me), but currently I can't find it anymore. But I remember general problems with quotes in or around batch file names with `%~0`. Perhaps you should store the value before changing the directory

Comment: @Stephan That's also strange. But unfortunately, this batch file references other files, so I need the `%~dp0` as the script may be called from other directories. I.e. someone calls it from the command line from another directory or it is run as admin

Comment: @jeb If that is the only solution, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: @jeb, in relation to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607958/#comment103526928_58607958), was it [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12141482)?

Comment: @Compo That actually really helped. Thanks

Comment: @Compo Yes, that link seems the right one, I see now that it was MC ND who explained the real problem. And I'm happy that I rebuild the wheel nearly the same way as I did it last time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit's to [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26851883/4601149) from [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd).

> **From the C# code**
>
> - Don't use quotes : cmd /c batchfile.cmd
> - If quotes are needed, use the full path in the call to the batch file. That way %0 contains all the needed information.

By doing `cmd /c call "%~dp0Bat 2.bat"` the batch file contains all the information needed and it works as expected. Why this is the case, I am not sure, but it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with a helper function (:repair).

The `%0` in a called function normally contains the function name (even `%~0`), but if any modifier is used `%~<modifier>0`, then the originally batch file name is used.

The fixed version of bat2.bat

```
@echo OFF
setlocal

echo "%~dp0"
cd /d "%~dp0..\.."
echo current-dir: %__cd__%
echo Wrong value "%~dp0"

call :repair

endlocal
exit /b

:repair
echo ### repair "%~dp0"
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Compo's comment helped me find the solution.