# Pass multiple variables to binary

Tags: batch-file

In unix command line you can do this

```
tempvar=ABC mybinary
```

apparently you can do the same in Windows batch, but in case you need multiple assignments to pass, `export` in unix would do the trick. How could you pass multiple variables to `mybynary` in a Windows Batch script?

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. Information about Windows commands and Windows command processor syntax

There can be executed `help` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) to get output an incomplete list of Windows commands with a brief description. Any Windows command can be executed with `/?` as argument to get output the usage help for the command. The execution of `cmd /?` results in output of the usage help of Windows command processor `cmd.exe` which is the Windows equivalent for `man sh` (or `man bash`, man `dash`, `man ksh`, `man zsh`, etc.) in a Linux terminal window.

For most Windows commands, but not all of them, it is also possible to run `help` with the command name as argument. `help set` and `set /?` output both the usage help of the command to define environment variables.

There is additionally:

- the **Microsoft** documentation about the [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- the [A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/) by **SS64**
- the [Windows CMD Shell How-to guides and examples](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) by **SS64**

[SS64](https://ss64.com/) offers also comprehensive documentations for other scripting languages on Windows, Linux and Mac.

There are two types of Windows commands:

1. the internal commands of `cmd.exe` like `echo`, `copy`, `set`
2. the so called external commands like `chcp`, `find`, `robocopy`

The external Windows commands are executables in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` with file extension `.com` like `chcp.com` (rare) or file extension `.exe` like `find.exe`, `robocopy.exe` and `where.exe` (most external Windows commands).

There are on 64-bit Windows two system directories:

- `%SystemRoot%\System32` contains the 64-bit executables and dynamic linked libraries.
- `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` contains the 32-bit executables and dynamic linked libraries.

The Windows commands usually exist in both system directories as 32-bit and 64-bit executable on 64-bit Windows. But there are some executables existing only as 64-bit executables.

That is important to know if a 32-bit application starts on 64-bit Windows the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` to process a batch file because of the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) starts in this case 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and all commands found via the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` in folder `%SystemRoot%\System32` being by default the first folder path in **system** environment variable `PATH` are in real searched and executed from directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` in the 32-bit execution environment on 64-bit Windows.

In a command prompt window are entered by a user a command usually with just its file name and so the Windows command processor has to search for a suitable file to execute. For details about this process read: [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

In a batch file can be used also only the file name of an external Windows command, but it is advisable to specify them with full qualified file names for the following reasons:

1. The batch file an external command specified like `%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe` instead of just `find` are more fail safe and secure as the batch file does not depend on the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` defined outside of the batch file which are quite often modified by programs and users, especially the environment variable `PATH`.
2. The batch file is executed faster as the Windows command processor has not to search in file system for the executables.

The external Windows command `where` can be used to find out if a Windows command is an internal command or an external command. The execution of `where set` in a command prompt window results in output of an error message (hopefully) while `where find` results in output of file qualified file name of `find` (hopefully found first in `%SystemRoot%\System32` with file extension `.exe`).

##### 2. Define one or more environment variables for an executable

The command to define environment variables on Windows is **SET**. So this command must be used to define an environment variable which an executable evaluates on execution. An environment variable like `tempvar` can be defined as follows:

1. `set tempvar=ABC`
2. `set "tempvar=ABC"`

The second syntax is highly recommended, but requires enabled command extensions which is the case by default, but which does not mean that command extensions are always enabled. Please read my answer on: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) There is explained in full details why `set "variable=value"` is the recommended syntax.

The environment variable(s) evaluated by an executable can be defined on separate lines before execution of the executable or on same command line.

Definition of the environment variable and execution of the executable on separate command lines:

```
set "tempvar=ABC"
mybinary
```

Definition of the environment variable and execution of the executable on one command line:

```
set "tempvar=ABC" & mybinary
```

[Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explains the operator `&` used in the single command line variant.

A batch file writer should avoid replacing one of the predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows), except a predefined environment variable should be intentionally redefined in a batch script.

##### 3. Define one or more environment variables just for an executable

Environment variables defined inside a batch file for an executable are still defined after the executable terminated itself. Therefore the environment variables are readable for any other executable started next by `cmd.exe` in same batch file or even after batch file processing finished depending on how `cmd.exe` was started for processing the batch file and the execution environment defined by the batch file itself.

The Windows command processor uses the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to run an executable like any other Windows application capable running an executable. `cmd.exe` uses always **NULL** for the `CreateProcess` function parameter `lpEnvironment` which results in `CreateProcess` making a copy of the current environment variables list of `cmd.exe` for the executable started next.

The commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** can be used in a batch file to define the environment variables evaluated by an executable just for the executable as the code below demonstrates.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem The two command lines above define completely the execution environment for the
rem batch file and so the batch file does not depend anymore on settings outside of
rem the batch file.

rem Define MyVariable1 and undefine MyVariable2
set "MyVariable1=Demo"
set "MyVariable2="
rem Verify that with an output of all environment variables of
rem which name starts with the string MyVariable with their values.
echo(
echo My variables defined in batch script at top:
echo(
set MyVariable

setlocal
set "MyVariable1=Other value for execuable"
set "MyVariable2=Defined also for executable"
echo(
echo My variables defined for mybinary:
echo(
set MyVariable
if exist mybinary mybinary
endlocal

echo(
echo My variables defined after execution of mybinary:
echo(
set MyVariable

endlocal

echo(
echo My variables as defined outside of the batch file:
echo(
set MyVariable
echo(
pause
```

I recommend to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) in addition to execution of `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` in a command prompt window to get full knowledge on what is done by these two commands in background.

##### 4. Referencing files in batch file directory with full path

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` can be executed for processing a batch file from within any directory which means the current working directory can be any directory. For that reason it is advisable to reference other files in the directory of the batch file with full path and with file extension instead of just the file name.

The usage of just `mybinary` results in searching in **current working directory** for a file with name `mybinary` having one of the file extensions as listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` if the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` is not defined. In other words the successful execution of `mybinary` depends on execution environment settings defined outside of the batch file which is not good.

So it is advisable to use `"%~dp0mybinary.exe"` in the batch file to reference the executable with full qualified file name whereby `%~dp0` references the drive and path (can be also a UNC path) of argument 0 which is the full folder path of the batch file always ending with a backslash and therefore concatenated without an additional backslash with file name `mybinary.exe`.

The usage of `"%~dp0mybinary.exe"` has following advantages regarding to execution of this executable:

1. It does not matter anymore how the environment variable `PATHEXT` is defined.
2. It does not matter anymore if the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` is defined or not.
3. It does not matter anymore what is the current working directory on execution of the batch file as long as the executable is good coded and does not expect that the directory containing the executable is the working directory to access other files in that directory.

For completeness regarding usage of `%~dp0` see also:
[What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)