# Apache Server root

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I have downloded Apache Server from Apachelounge for installation on windows 10 to create My own WAMP. However on windows 10 Apache Service do not start automatically though I have set, the log shows an error

> Server root should be valid directory

I have set the Server root directory as C:/Apache/Apache24

Can anybody tell me what should be exactly Server root directory?
Also can anybody show me from where i can find well prepared httpd.conf page which also shows web domain registered to apache?

Answer (score -1):

You can try run the `setup_xampp.bat` which will automatically set the paths for your machine. 
For reference, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548768/apache-could-not-be-started-serverroot-must-be-a-valid-directory-and-unable-to).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13601604)

Comment: @abarisone Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I have not downloaded Xampp, I have downloaded three software 1)Apache Lounge 2)PHP 3)Mysql, out of this i have configured php and mysql in separate folder, i have also downloaded and configured Apache in Apache folder, but Apache do not start automatically, on windows service even i click start it do not start and shows logs   Sever root should be valid directory.