# Retrieving absolute path of the folder in windows batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, absolute-path

I have a folder that has the batch file, along with a jar file and JRE. Batch file is supposed to run the jar by invoking the JRE. I know it would be something like:

```
   <jre-path>/bin/java.exe -jar <jar-path>Executable.jar
```

In batch file, how I would retrieve the absolute path of the folder which has all these jar and jre? There is an answer on SO for the question : [what is the current directory in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420078/3615029) that suggests to use `%~dp0`, but how would I use this in correct way for the command I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you decide relative path between the jar and the running script. The script will detect its location using the answer you already mentioned. (%~dp0  gives the directory)

```
mydir=%~dp0 
jardir=%mydir%/ 
..
java.exe -jar %jardir%/exectuble.jar
```

Another approach will be use product like launch4j[enter link description here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options). You can access the install location from variable, provide user a nice looking launch icon, include jre with your packaging and more.

Comment: jar file is in the same folder, i.e. no subdirectory. So I think I can use `java.exe -jar %mydir%/exectuble.jar`, Right? Also, is it not needed to specify the location of `java.exe` (keepng in mind that there may be a case where JRE is not installed on the machine where batch file is executing) ?

Comment: If there is no java.exe on the machine, you cannot run java.exe.  Please consider the other option of packaging your product.

Comment: I just asked for confirmation, let me just test the snippet to mark this question resolved.

Comment: I edited my answer to suite your case.  If you just want some java, you can always use java.exe without absolute path. Normally java installation creates a dummy java.exe in system/win32 which will redirect to correct path.