# Batch: Relative directory/path

Tags: batch-file, copy, relative-path

I created a small harmless batch virus (a prank), it is finished (on a USB) but I don't want to manually copy it and then I ran to a problem...

**Is there a way to copy files relatively, from where the actual batch file is?**

**Something like this maybe**:

> copy "~Virus.bat" "%appdata%/microsoft/windows/start menu/programs/startup"

instead of

> copy "G:\Files\Folder1\Folder2\Virus.bat" "%appdata%/microsoft/windows/start menu/programs/startup"

If somebody can help please do... **Thanks**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file) may solve your problem, but a short answer for copying your file is using `%~dp0`. As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file/4420078#4420078), this will give you the current path.

Try this:

```
copy "%~dp0Virus.bat" "%appdata%/microsoft/windows/start menu/programs/startup"
```