# Python runs from batch file when clicked, but not when dragging and dropping files

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I'm having an issue with running a pretty simple Python script from a Windows batch file.

The Batch Code is:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "V34_File_Converter.py" %*
pause
```

where the "V34_File_Converter.py" file is located in the same folder as the batch file.

The Python Code is:

```
import os,sys
import psse34
import psspy

print('we are in the program')

args_num = len(sys.argv) - 1

psspy.psseinit()

for f_name in sys.argv[1:]:

    print f_name

    psspy.read(0,f_name)
    f_name_out = os.path.splitext(f_name)[0] + "_V34.RAW"
    psspy.rawd_2(0,1,[1,1,1,0,0,0,0],0,f_name_out)
```

The main issue is when I double click the Batch file, the program runs fine, printing the first message and initializing the PSSE program. However, when I drag and drop files onto the batch script, I get the following Error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'V34_File_Converter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Which is strange, considering it finds that file no problem if no other arguments are passed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Comment: and actually this is nothing of a python issue - you'd have the same results if it was ruby or perl etc...

Answer (score 0):

The Python script file `V34_File_Converter.py` is obviously in the directory of the batch file because of referenced in batch file without file path. The batch file directory is set as current directory by Windows before starting `cmd.exe` to process the batch file on double clicking the batch file. There are two exceptions:

1. The batch file is started with using *Run as administrator* instead of double clicking it resulting often in setting `%SystemRoot%\System32` as current directory.
2. A double clicked batch file is stored on a network resource accessed using a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) in which case `%SystemRoot%` is set by default as current directory.

But batch files can be in general executed from any other directory, too. Therefore it is advisable to reference other files in a batch file with their full qualified file names.

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `call /?` and read the output help explaining how the batch file arguments can be referenced from within a batch file. Argument 0 is always the string used to start processing of the batch file.

The solution here is:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%~dp0V34_File_Converter.py" %*
```

`%~dp0` references drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file itself, i.e. the path to the batch file directory which obviously contains also the Python script file. The path string referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash. For that reason no additional backslash should be used on concatenating this path with a file or folder name.

See also:

- [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/)
- [What is the reason for batch file path referenced with %~dp0 sometimes changes on changing directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141482/)
- [Why does 'Run as administrator' change (sometimes) batch file's current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622469/)
- [CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071585/)
- Microsoft documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)