# Different CMDs Different behaviour

Tags: cmd

**Update2**:

Now, when I know, that x32 is the problem I debugged into the script using powershell_ise_x32 and found out, that `$Word.Documents` is `null`.
So Powershell-API for Word has a different behaviour in x32 PowerShell, then in 64bit.

[image]

---

**Update**:

The error occurs, when using PowerShell x32 and occurs NOT on PowerShell 64bit. That was really it. Powershell x32 was executed because I started it from the Total Commander 32bit.

The question is now - why 32bit and 64bit PowerShell have different behaviour?

---

**Initial Question:**

I wrote a powershell script, to convert my WordDocuments and merge them to one. 
I wrote a Batch script, to start this powershell script.

When I execute the script directly in "**Powershell ISE**" the script **works** fine.

When I execute the batch script **as Administrator** via context menu, the script **reports errors**. In this case the **C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cmd.exe** is executed.

When I execute another cmd.exe  found on my system **as Administrator** - everything **works** fine:
"**C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_9c209ff6532b42d7\cmd.exe**"

Why do I have different behaviour in different cmd.exe? What are those different cmd.exe?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Batch Script:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"

powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "%~dp0%DocxToPdf.ps1" 
pause
```

Powershell Script

```
$FilePath = $PSScriptRoot
$Pdfsam = "D:\Programme\PDFsam\bin\run-console.bat"




$Files = Get-ChildItem "$FilePath\*.docx"
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
if(-not $?){
    throw "Failed to open Word"
}

# Convert all docx files to pdf
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    Write-Host "Word Object: "  $Word
    Write-Host "File Object: "  $Word $File
    Write-Host "FullName prop:" $File.FullName

    # open a Word document, filename from the directory
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)

    # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename
    $Name=($Doc.FullName).Replace("docx","pdf")

    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.SaveAs([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
    $Doc.Close()
}

# check errors
if(-not $?){
    Write-Host("Stop because an error occurred")
    pause
    exit 0
}

# wait until the conversion is done
Start-Sleep -s 15


# Now concat all pdfs to one single pdf
$Files = Get-ChildItem "$FilePath\*.pdf" | Sort-Object

Write-Host $Files.Count

if ($Files.Count -gt 0) {

    $command = "" 
    Foreach ($File in $Files) {
        $command += " -f "
        $command += "`"" + $File.FullName + "`""
    }

    $command += " -o `"$FilePath\Letter of application.pdf`" -overwrite concat"
    $command = $Pdfsam + $command
    echo $command

    $path = Split-Path -Path $Pdfsam -Parent 
    cd $path

    cmd /c $command

}else{
    Write-Host "No PDFs found for concatenation"
}




Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue...";
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown");
```

Comment: Read the Microsoft article about [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) and other WoW64 pages. 32-bit `cmd.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\Syswow64` is started when the application starting it is a 32-bit application. In 32-bit applications `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` can be executed to start 64-bit `cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows. See also answer on ['Run As Administrator' Changes Batch File Current Directory (Sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655249/3074564).

Comment: Sorry, but how is it related to my question, that 32 and 64 bit versions of cmd exist? And changing directories is fixed by `cd /d "%~dp0" ` in my batch script

Comment: There should be two cmd.exe files in the WinSxS directory, both of which are hard linked to their normal locations, the 64-bit build in System32 and the 32-bit build in SysWOW64. Never use files directly from the system's WinSxS directory.

Comment: If you're having a problem with the PowerShell script using 32-bit powershell.exe, I suggest you do as @Mofi suggested. Try running the 64-bit version explicitly from 32-bit CMD: `C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. This path will *only work* in 32-bit CMD. The virtual "SysNative" directory doesn't exist for 64-bit applications, which is an unfortunate and annoying oversight in my opinion.

Comment: Also, figure out why running a batch script from Explorer is using 32-bit CMD. Something is either misconfigured in the .bat file association or maybe you're using 32-bit Explorer.

Comment: The error occurs, when using PowerShell x32 and occurs NOT on PowerShell 64bit. That was really it. Powershell x32 was executed because I started it from the Total Commander 32bit. The question is not - why 32bit and 64bit PowerShell have different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I've found `$PSScriptRoot` to be unreliable.

```
$FilePath = $PSScriptRoot;
$CurLocation = Get-Location;
$ScriptLocation = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Write-Host "FilePath = [$FilePath]";
Write-Host "CurLocation = [$CurLocation]";
Write-Host "ScriptLocation = [$ScriptLocation]";
```

Results:

```
O:\Data>powershell ..\Script\t.ps1
FilePath = []
CurLocation = [O:\Data]
ScriptLocation = [O:\Script]
```

As to the differences between the various `cmd.exe` implementations, I can't really answer that.  I should have thought they'd be functionally identical, but maybe there's 32/64-bit differences that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs, when using PowerShell x32 and occurs NOT on PowerShell 64bit.

I debugged into the script using powershell_ise_x32 and found out, that `$Word.Documents` is `null`.

This is because on my system Word 64bit is installed.

Comment: Does `$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application` succeed? If not, maybe it's an in-process COM component that's only available in a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: It succeeds. Look at the screnshot, $Word is not null