# Why won't a Batch file start in the directory it was executed in?

Tags: batch-file

I am programming a DOS-like shell, but it starts in %UserProfile% instead of %UserProfile%\Desktop\Coding projects\CM-DOS.
The actual shell, kernel.bat's code is:

```
@echo off
type INFO.txt
pause
```

INFO.txt is in the same directory as kernel.bat (CM-DOS).
It says:

> CM-DOS is a FREE, open-source Disk Operating System by Tristan
> Carpenter. If anyone trys to sell you a paid copy of CM-DOS, send me
> an e-mail at tristan4@mail.com. Please use this DOS shell kindly. This
> shell is licensed under the MIT License. Do whatever you want with the
> shell, create closed-source versions, fork it, I don't really care.

The script tries to type "%UserProfile%\INFO.txt", which doesn't exist.
How can I start the file in it's actual directory, instead of %UserProfile%.

Comment: According to the wording, you might be trying to create own OS. However it'd be at best a script ran within an OS (Windows or DOS or anything capable of running Batchfile). Writing an OS is a different beast to tame. You might want to check [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org) and also [this article](https://medium.com/@andrewimm/writing-a-dos-clone-in-2019-70eac97ec3e1) seems to be going in the right direction as well.

Comment: Use in the batch file `type "%~dp0INFO.txt"` to reference the text file with the fully qualified file name using the full path of the batch file (argument 0) always ending with a backslash. There is never the guarantee that the directory containing the executed batch file is the current directory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Comment: The process starting `cmd.exe` to process the batch file determines the current directory on calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which has the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` which is either a null pointer or a pointer to the string with the path of the current directory. So `cmd.exe` itself does not set the current directory for itself, it is done by the process starting `cmd.exe` like `explorer.exe` or `schtasks.exe`.

Comment: Example: [Why does 'Run as administrator' change (sometimes) batch file's current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31655249/3074564)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the script (clicking or navigating (`cd <folder>`) and `.\kernel.bat`) and the current folder isn't, well, the **current** folder, then something is off with either your console setup or there is an additional code executed in the background. Try to `echo %CD%` to see what the folder is and check the prompt string usually in the shape of:

```
C:\Users\Username>
```

which is the default path if you run `cmd.exe` as a user or:

```
C:\Windows\System32>
```

if you run as an Administrator / user with elevated privileges.

This can be changed though [with `regedit.exe`](https://superuser.com/a/87400/571014).

However what you might be seeing is that you run your code (`kernel.bat` or however you name it) which might display the first path before execution or after the last command you might be dropped into a shell. Neither should be the case according to the code, yet it can happen if you started `cmd.exe`, then wrote `cmd.exe` (i.e. spawned another shell) and then ran your script.

What I suspect is that you're running the code like this:

```
C:\Users\You> .\Desktop\Coding projects\CM-DOS\kernel.bat
```

in which case the `%CD%` would be `C:\Users\You` and `type` command would be looking for `C:\Users\You\INFO.txt`. A better solution is simply creating a variable for the folder where your script is located - which is [provided automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765/5994041), it's `%~dp0` (`echo %~dp0`) and with that you can do:

```
echo off
type "%~dp0INFO.txt"
pause
```

to make it location independent, or better said, to access relatively according to the `kernel.bat` (the current script)'s location.

Answer (score -2):

You can add `cd %CD%` 
 and %CD% stands for the current direction. 
 the final code would be

```
@echo off
cd %CD%
type INFO.txt
pause
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still get "The system can't find the file specified." error.

Comment: try this  `@echo off
cd %CD% & type INFO.txt
pause`

Comment: `cd %CD%` is completely useless as it changes the current directory to current directory and not to the directory containing the batch file. Try it out. Create a batch file with the two lines `@echo Current directory is: "%CD%"` and `@echo Batch file directory is: "%~dp0"` and save the batch file with name `Demo.cmd` on your `Desktop` or in your `Documents` folder. Then open a command prompt window and run first `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%"` and next `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Demo.cmd"` or `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Demo.cmd"`. You see the difference between current and batch file directory.

Comment: Use `cd /D "%~dp0."` instead of `cd %CD%`. Next time please try your code yourself before you post an answer!