# Starting a nodejs http-server using a BAT file when the directory name contains a space

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file on windows, which i want to be able to copy to any new folder and doubleclick to start a http server. It only contains one line which is:

```
http-server %~dp0
```

The `%~dp0`picks up the full path to whatever directory the .bat file is currently in. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420078/2570277) for that.

It works well when none of the folders in the file path contain a space.

How can i modify the batch file to account for situations where some directories in the path contain a space in the name?

cheers

PS: Im new to this :)

Comment: thats what quotes were made for

Comment: or you could point me in the right direction.....

Comment: `http-server "%~dp0"`

Comment: Hi, thanks, i tried that but when i try to connect to localhost from the browser i get the error "This site can’t be reached". I tried adding /index.html after the word local host with the same result. The good thing now however is i can see the entire path to the website folder on the commandline screen. Do i need to add something else? cheers

Answer (score 1):

It turns out removing the `%~dp0` and just having `http-server` and nothing else in the batch file makes it work!

It then serves up whatever is in the current directory as shown:

[image]