# How to set a go to a directory and execute a command in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

During the deployment of the windows application that I make, I have to run a few commands in the CommandPrompt to update the database. I was thinking of making a batch file to automate this process so that the user can update the database just by double-clicking the batch file. Following is the screenshot for the same.

[image: CommandPrompt Screenshot]

I want my batch file to go to the current directory where the .bat file is located.
Then i want to execute the DBUpdater exe file against the config file.

I am new to batch programming so anything informative will help a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file named `DBUpdater.bat` in any directory of your choice with the below script:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
DBUpdater.v15.2.exe OfficeManagement.win.exe.config
```

This assumes that the `OfficeManagement.win.exe.config` file exists in the same directory as batch file and that `DBUpdater.v15.2.exe` is recognized as a global command.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like Magic. Would you care more into explaining how each of these symbols work? It'll be a huge gainer for me.

Comment: @taimuralam - Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file) to see how I go to the current directory.

Comment: please go to command prompt and enter `HELP CALL` for useful Information about that symbols :-)

Comment: Do i not have to use anymore ECHO and EXIT commands after the last line

Comment: @taimuralam - That's not required if your application launches in background. If it doesn't, you may need to launch it in a separate command prompt and exit the one running this batch script. Feel free to customize it as per your needs.