# How to resolve path in env variable in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

In node I want to set `START_DIR` on `process.env` to process.cwd().

How to that within scripts `package.json`?

I can't use env file for example. this app not using env file loader and I can't change that.

for example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set SOMEDIR=process.cwd() && node app",

....

console.log('res', process.env.START_DIR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, `process.env` represents the environment of the Node process at runtime, so whatever environment variables are visible to the Node process can be accessed in your modules as `process.env.WHATEVER_VAR`.

And why not just call `process.cwd()` from your app's code? It will return the path from which you execute the node command, or in this case `npm start`. It would be helpful to know more about what you're trying to accomplish, as I don't see why you would want to do what I think you're trying to do.

If you *really* want to do *exactly* what you described, you can use `node -e "console.log('something')"` To output `something` to the shell. Here's how it might look when you run `npm start` **from a bash shell in the directory you want `process.cwd()` to return**. (I'm not sure of the Windows equivalent):

`"start": "export START_DIR=$(node -e \"console.log(process.cwd());\") && node app"`

There are other options though. You could refer to the operating system's built-in variable representing the working directory. Looks like you may be using Windows, so that variable's name would be `CD`. I believe the full command would look something like this:

`set SOMEDIR=%CD% && node app`

Or, if you're starting the process from a bash shell (Linux and MacOS):

`export SOMEDIR=$PWD && node app`

You can also just access these variables directly in your scripts using  `process.env.CD` or `process.env.PWD`.

The only danger with this method is that it assumes `CD` / `PWD` hasn't been manually set to some other value. In Windows, one way to circumvent this is to create a batch file wherever you're calling `npm start` from. In the file, execute the same command but replace `%CD%` with `%~dp0`, which [refers to the path containing the file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420078) Then set `start` to a Windows  command to execute the file, something like `call ./file.bat`.

Similarly, in a bash environment create a shell script and use `$(dirname $0)` instead of `$PWD`. Make it executable with `chmod +x name_of_file` and set `start` to `bash ./name_of_file`.

One last thing: if the name of the variable doesn't matter, `package.json` can tell npm to create environment variables prefixed by `npm_config_`. More info in the [npm config documentation.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)