# How to make `git log` show CommitDate by default instead of AuthorDate?

Tags: git

`git log` by default shows the AuthorDate and you need to do something like `git log --format=fuller` or other formatter options to make it show CommitDate. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Lacking that, what would be the format string to exactly mimick the default one but with CommitDate? Then I could use git as a bash function and override git log.

Comment: You want that when you write `git log`, that it shows you the *CommitDate* and not as default the *AuthorDate*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is documented mainly in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), under the `format.pretty` section.  Note that `git log --format=fuller` does the same thing as `git log --pretty=fuller`: `pretty` is the original name for this,<sup>1</sup> and the setup is described (and controlled) under the original name.

Note that you can define your own *named formats*, which you can then invoke with `git log --pretty=name`.

> Lacking that, what would be the format string to exactly mimick the default one but with CommitDate?

You'll likely want this even with the knowledge about `format.pretty`.  For this, consult [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and search for the **PRETTY FORMATS** section.  The default is a bit complicated due to colors, which I omit here, and besides that, inserts `Merge:` conditionally, for which there is no format directive available.  The default `--pretty` is `medium`, which is roughly:

```
commit %H%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate:  %ad%n%n%B
```

To switch from author date to committer date, use `%cd` (though it's usually wise to also switch to committer name and email address, i.e., `%cn` and `%ce`, when doing so).

---

<sup>1</sup>Back in the bad old days, you had to run `git log --pretty=format:directives` rather than the shorter `git log --format=directives` or `git log --pretty=tformat:directives`.  These days `--pretty` is smarter and detects whether you've given it a named format, such as `full` or `fuller`, or a set of directives.

Comment: Note `cmd.exe` interprets the`%cd%` in `%cd%n` as an [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420078/44729) during interactive `git log --format=...` use but it works fine if it's in `.gitconfig`.