# Run python script with .bat that imports functions from other scripts

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run my python script through .bat. The script imports functions from other scripts and this works fine when running in the IDE(Spyder) however when I run the .bat I get the error unable to import module.

.bat is as follows

```
"D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" "D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\test.py"
```

I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\test.py", line 1, in 
from SFTPDownload import downloadSFTP
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SFTPDownload'

What do I need to add to the .bat to pick up my function in SFTPDownload.py. This is in the same folder as the test.py.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `SFTPDownload.py` is your file in folder `D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\ ` then you have to go to this folder `cd D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\ ` before you run python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SFTPDownload.py` is your file in folder `D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\`
then you have to go to this folder before you run python script

```
  cd D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\

  D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe test.py
```

---

System may run your batch in different folder (which is used as `Current Working Directory`) and then python script searchs your files in this folder.

In Python you can check `Current Working Directory`

```
 print( os.getcwd() )
```

---

See also: [What is the current directory in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file)

---

Eventually in python script before importing `SFTPDownload` you can add folder `D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\` to special list `sys.path` which python uses to search imported files.

```
 import sys

 sys.path.insert(0, r'D:\Users\User\Documents\programming\')

 import SFTPDownload
```

to make it more universal (so it would work when you move `test.py` and `SFTPDownload.py` to different folder) you can try

```
 import sys
 import os

 APP_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
 #APP_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

 sys.path.insert(0, APP_FOLDER)

 import SFTPDownload
```

Comment: hello @furas, i am facing a similar issue buy my import module 'Aladdin' is in a different folder (and thus filepath). how can i get it to work in that case?

Comment: @Zack if you have module `/full/path/other_folder/Aladdin` then you have to insert `/full/path/other_folder` without `Aladdin`. If you have it in subfolder `APP_FOLDER/subfolder/Aladdin` then you can use `os.path.join(APP_FOLDER, "subfolder")` to create `full path` to insert.