# Get last command line argument in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to get last argument passed to windows batch script, how can I do that?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest and perhaps most reliable way would be to just use `cmd`'s own parsing for arguments and `shift` then until no more are there.

Since this destroys the use of `%1`, etc. you can do it in a subroutine:

```
@echo off
call :lastarg %*
echo Last argument: %LAST_ARG%
goto :eof

:lastarg
  set "LAST_ARG=%~1"
  shift
  if not "%~1"=="" goto lastarg
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 13):

This will get the count of arguments:

```
set count=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a count+=1
```

To get the actual last argument, you can do

```
for %%a in (%*) do set last=%%a
```

Note that this will fail if the command line has unbalanced quotes - the command line is re-parsed by `for` rather than directly using the parsing used for `%1` etc.

Comment: Why did you answer with the argument count? That wasn't what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

An enhanced version of [joey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807218/7485823):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:test
    :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807218/7485823
    CALL :lastarg xxx %*
    ECHO Last argument: [%XXX%]
    CALL :skiplastarg yyy %*
    ECHO skip Last argument: [%yyy%]
GOTO :EOF

:: Return all but last arg in variable given in %1
:skiplastarg returnvar args ...
    SETLOCAL
        SET $return=%1
        SET SKIP_LAST_ARG=
        SHIFT
    :skiplastarg_2
        IF NOT "%~2"=="" SET "SKIP_LAST_ARG=%SKIP_LAST_ARG% %1"
        SHIFT
        IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO skiplastarg_2
    ENDLOCAL&CALL SET "%$return%=%SKIP_LAST_ARG:~1%"
GOTO :EOF

:: Return last arg in variable given in %1
:lastarg returnvar args ...
    SETLOCAL
      SET $return=%1
      SET LAST_ARG=
  SHIFT
    :LASTARG_2
      SET "LAST_ARG=%1"
      SHIFT
      IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO lastarg_2
    ENDLOCAL&call SET %$return%=%LAST_ARG%
GOTO :EOF
```

Run it with the arguments:

> abe "ba na na" "cir cle"

and get:

> Last argument: ["cir cle"]
>
> skip Last argument: [abe "ba na na"]

Comment: Thank you, sometimes it helps to process just the last couple of arguments differently but pass on the rest as is

Answer (score 0):

```
set first=""
set last=""
for %%a in (%*) do (
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if !first!=="" (set first=!last!) else (set first=!first! !last!)
set last=%%a

)
ENDLOCAL & set "last=%last%" & set "first=%first%"
echo %last%  "and" %first%
```