# Replace several characters in substring in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to replace all occurrences of several characters in an argument to batch file:

**helper.bat**

```
@echo off

echo %1
call:replace_newline_characters_and_additional_quotes arg %%1
echo %arg%
goto:eof

:replace_newline_characters_and_additional_quotes
set in=%2
set tmp=%in:\n=|%
set %1=%tmp:""=\"%
goto:eof
```

Run it as

helper "1""2\n3"

**Output**

> "1""2\n3"
>   "3"" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Remove all quotes and replace newlines with `|` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Replace all "" with \" and replace all \n with |

Comment: so you want output as: `"1\"2|3"` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP In this case, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set str=%1

set str=%str:""=\"%
set str=%str:\n=^|%

echo %str:|=^|%

pause
```

Just worked for me with your test case.

You get the `"3"" is not recognized` error because of the pipe `|` character, as it means that CMD is trying to pass the text before the `|` to the 'program' after it, which is why you'll notice I've used `^|` to 'escape' the pipe and stop it from having it's special meaning

Answer (score 3):

You should switch to delayed expansion, as it's safe to use special characters.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "param1=%1"
echo !param1!
call :replace_newline_characters_and_additional_quotes arg param1
echo !arg!
exit /b

:replace_newline_characters_and_additional_quotes
set "in=!%2!"
set "tmp=!in:\n=|!"
set "%1=!tmp:""=\"!"
exit /b
```

The only problematic line is `set "param1=%1"`, as it would fail in the case of calling

```
helper "&"^&
```

And it's not easy to avoid this, but there exists a solution at
[SO: Get list of passed arguments in Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338799/463115)