# Split into equal parts and convert many mp4 videos using ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a ton of videos I need to convert from mp4 to wmv using ffmpeg and break up each file into 10 minute segments, but I am a total cmd scripting newb (in fact, I am a scripting newb :)

After spending six hours trying to find an answer, I thought I would bring it to you guys.

The code I have is working a little bit, but I need to be able to read data coming from the command line and send it back into the script for evaluation. I am not sure what code ffmpeg will spit out when it is done processing a video file (when the timestamp reaches an end), but this FOR loop just keeps on trying to create new file segments even though the video is over. This is what I saw when it tried to create a new file, so I think it might work to search for this:

frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A

This is the code I have come up with so far (Don't laugh :)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
set hour=00

for /L %%i IN (1,1,10) do (
:Beginning
    set /a start=%%i-1
        set end=%%i
        if !start! lss 10 set start=!start!0
        if !end! lss 10 set end=!end!0
        ffmpeg -ss !hour!:!start!:00 -i "%%a" -b:v 1500k -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 -t !hour!:!end!:00 "Converted\%%~na-!hour!-!start!-!end!.wmv"
        if end==60 CALL :Increment
    )   
)

:Increment
    set /a !hour!+1
    set %%i=1
    GOTO :Beginning
pause
```

Based on reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat) was thinking something like this might go in the code, but not sure what to do with it:

```
set "dosstring=%*"

echo.!dosstring!|findstr /C:"frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A" >nul 2>&1
```

Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: I don't think the label `:Beginning` will work inside (), put it before `FOR %%A` [look at the bugs section](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) . Also test your batch with `echo` in front of `ffmpeg` command. Seems infintie loop in `goto :Beginning` because there is no `IF` statement

Comment: hehe my coding skills are what you might call jury rigged. That statement was strung together from like 10 different web pages. I will try what you said, but I have a feeling I can't get it to work lol

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient method is to invoke `ffmpeg` just once per file and use its [segmenting](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples-5) feature.

The segments will be numbered sequentially so if you absolutely need to include timestamps in the name we'll also generate a list of the segment's timestamps in CSV format:

```
tmp000.wmv,0.000000,60.281000
tmp001.wmv,60.281000,120.041000
```

Then parse it and rename the segments.

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.mp4) do (

    ffmpeg -i "%%a" ^
        -f segment -segment_time 10:00 -segment_list tmp.csv -reset_timestamps 1 ^
        -b:v 1500k -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 converted\tmp%%03d.wmv

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=, tokens=1-3" %%b in (tmp.csv) do (
        set sec=%%c & set sec=!sec:.*=!
        set /a hour="sec / 3600"
        set /a mins1="sec / 60 %% 60" & set mins1=0!mins1!
        set sec=%%d & set sec=!sec:.*=!
        set /a mins2="sec / 60 %% 60" & set mins2=0!mins2!

        ren "converted\%%b" "%%~na-!hour!-!mins1:~-2!-!mins2:~-2!.*"
    )
    endlocal
    del tmp.csv
)
pause
```

This example won't rename files with `!` in the name as I didn't want to overcomplicate the code to work around this case.

Comment: Wow that is awesome thank you so much :) I'm sure it took you two seconds lol. It worked almost perfectly, but I tried a long file that produced 12 segments, and it named them perfect until it got to:

-1-00-00
-1-10-10

Then it skipped to: -1-60-60 -1-70-70 etc. I am trying to fix it, but maybe it would just be easier to put a counter after the name with 10, 20, etc. I just need to know which files I watched, so anything sequential is good. I will try to figure it out, but you got the hardest part down. Thanks again! :)

Comment: very well batch, just tried to demux a small mp4 and it works smoothly. 
`%ffmpeg% -i "%%a" ^
        -f segment -segment_time 1:00 -segment_list tmp.csv -reset_timestamps 1 ^
        -codec copy -c:v copy -c:a copy -flags +global_header converted\tmp%%03d.mp4`
Thank you.

Comment: @bobafetta, there was a typo and the wrong formula to calculate the minutes after 1 hour length.

Comment: You are the best! I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help :D