# How to cut the videos per every 2MB using FFMpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

Hi i have **20MB** size video,I need to split this video as each part should be 2MB,
For this i google it and found **FFMpeg** library for splitting videos.

But this library splitting the videos based on **time-limit** suppose (00:00:02 to 00:00:06 seconds,Between this time period video splitted)

My requirement is, I want to cut the video per every **2MB** that's what my exact requirement not based on time limit.

I searched for this lot in google but i did not get solution can some one help me please.

### FFMpeg Command i used for splitting:-

```
String cmd[] = new String[]{"-i", inputFileUrl, "-ss", "00:00:02", "-c", "copy", "-t", "00:00:06",
                outputFileUrl};
        executeBinaryCommand(fFmpeg, cmd);

 public void executeBinaryCommand(FFmpeg ffmpeg, String[] command) {

        try {

            if (ffmpeg != null) {

                ffmpeg.execute(command,
                        new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(String response) {
                                System.out.println("failure====>" + response.toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                System.out.println("resposense====>" + response.toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(String response) {
                                System.out.println("on progress");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                System.out.println("start");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                System.out.println("Finish");
                            }
                        });
            }
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38261855/5726027

Comment: can you please edit my command ?

Comment: i mean can you edit-----> String cmd[] = new String[]{"-i", inputFileUrl, "-ss", "00:00:02", "-c", "copy", "-t", "00:00:06",
                outputFileUrl};

Comment: i have to cut the video per every two 2MB