# How to pass variable from php to bat file and read its result?

Tags: php, batch-file, variables, cmd, parameter-passing

How to pass variable from php to bat file and get back the result. I tried as follows

```
<?php
    $input="layer";
    echo shell_exec("F:\xampp\htdocs\flood_publish\123.bat",$input)
?>
```

and how to access and use that variable  in bat file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variables to bat files as arguments and the "$input" variable from your example contains the output of the bat file. So, if you want to pass a variable to a bat file and get the output back to the php, you should write something like this:

```
$input="layer";
exec("F:\xampp\htdocs\flood_publish\123.bat $input",$output);
print_r($output);
```

Here you can find more about how to use arguments in .bat files:
[Get list of passed arguments in Windows batch script (.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat)

Comment: You can access it with: %1    |                                                                                                           %0 is the filename, %1 is the first argument, %2 the second argument and so on.

Comment: ok thanks it's working  but one the way return result to php from bat it is giving  or printing (echo )  only array.

Comment: The function should be exec, the shell_exec return string and have 1 parameter only