# Get values from a batch(.bat) file and display the output in PHP

Tags: php, batch-file

Can any one tell me How to get values from a batch file and display the output in PHP script?
I have a simple batch file and simply want to display values in html/php format,

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to get the output of batch file then display in php

Comment: Have tried anything so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: Well. You need to describe where. If you have a WAMP, it's simple. Store the batch output in a file or directly into a SQL database. Read it out with PHP.

Comment: @RohanKhude I think he needs he output of a batch file to display it in php. Not sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from php to bat file and read its result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701896/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-bat-file-and-read-its-result)

Comment: @Athafoud 
I'm replying one week later! This is the thing I needed to do and i'm posting my piece of code here now..
I have a batch file (test.bat) and it contains few text. I want my php script to get values from test.bat file and dispaly in html/php page. Here's the code,

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){

  $instruction = 'D:xampp/htdocs/test/test.bat';
  $result = shell_exec($instruction);
                 print_r($result);
 } 
?>

Can someone tell me how to retrieve these values from the batch file and display in html/php?
Thanks.

Comment: pls add your code as an edit / update to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output from the .bat file to display in PHP, you can either run the file from PHP (not recommended) - this will only work on a computer running some version of DOS/Windows, so also not recommended, or you can run the file via the built-in scheduler in your operating system, outputting the values to a text-file or similar, and then read that file via PHP (a much safer option).

Although I'm guessing you're trying to do something you shouldn't be doing, so a bit more information might be needed.

Comment: I'm replying one week later! This is the thing I needed to do and i'm posting my piece of code here now..