# Sending arguments from a Python script to a batch script

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I'm trying to send arguments from a Python script to a batch script, but the batch file keeps failing.

This is what is written in the Python script:

```
cond = 'a'
sp3 = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(lua_caller_pth[:indx], 'lua_caller1.bat'), cond])

cond = 'b'
sp4 = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(lua_caller_pth[:indx], 'lua_caller1.bat'), cond])
```

And this is the batch script:

```
if %cond% == "a" (
    %CYGWINPATH%\bash -l -c "cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua &>../Object_Detection_Test_Script/xmllog1 \ && exit; bash";
)
if %cond% == "b" (
    %CYGWINPATH%\bash -l -c "cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua &>../Object_Detection_Test_Script/xmllog2 \ && exit; bash";
)
```

Comment: You're just passing the string 'a' as an argument, how does the batch script associate that with %cond%? You'd probably be better off using subprocess.call().

Comment: In the batch you've to use `%1` to receive the first command line argument not `%cond%`.

Answer (score 0):

In your script

```
%cond%
```

evaluates the environment varibale *cond*, that has not been set by your python program.

You need to evaluate the command line argument from your batch instead of evaluting the environment. See [Get list of passed arguments in Windows batch script (.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat) for more information how to do that.