# Pass variables to cURL in batch file

Tags: batch-file, variables, curl

I use a cURL command stored in .bat file.

I want to have variables implemented in the command, that will receive the value when I call the command to execute the .bat file.

Can anybody help with understading the syntax of:

- Passing variables to batch file
- Defining certain parts of the cURL command as variables (The parts in bold below)

Here is my cURL command (Parts in bold should be variables):

```
curl -k --user "usercode:" -d source="https://secure.4log.com/**431032**" https://api.pdfshift.io/v2/convert/ -d sandbox=true --output C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\**testpdf11**.pdf
```

Comment: so you want to run your batch as `somebatchfile.bat param1 param2` etc?

Comment: Call the batch file with two arguments/parameters,`BatchScript.cmd "431032" "testpdf11"` where the script would receive `431032` as `%~1` and `testpdf11` as `%~2`! `curl -k --user "usercode:" -d source="https://secure.4log.com/%~1" https://api.pdfshift.io/v2/convert/ -d sandbox=true --output C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\%~2.pdf`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of passed arguments in Windows batch script (.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send parameters you simply use:

```
curl %1 %2 %3
```

Each numeric value defines the position of the word after your batch.

so as a simple example, if you run only need to run something like:

```
mybatch.bat 1234 5678
```

That `1234` will be seen as `%1` and `5678` will be %2 and you will get:

```
source="https://secure.4log.com/%1" C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\%2.pdf
```

resulting to:

```
source="https://secure.4log.com/1234" C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\5678.pdf
```

If you plan on using paramters with space, or any quoted text for that matter, you should rather use `%~1` and `%~2` as it will remove the quotes for you.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE - It worked in the batch file only with a tilde ( %~1 and %~2) as @compo suggested in my original post comments

Comment: @YanivBen-Malka yes. I am aware. `~` simply removes double quotes. So if you use quoted input i.e paramters with a space, the you require the `~` simply test it by creating a test batch file and add code. `echo %1 %~1` then call it as `batchfile.bat "this line"` and you will see it will echo `"this line" this line`

Answer (score 1):

Parameters to the batchfile are referenced by `%1` for the first one, `%2` for the second one and so on until `%9` This makes your command:

```
curl -k --user "usercode:" -d source="https://secure.4log.com/%~1" https://api.pdfshift.io/v2/convert/ -d sandbox=true --output C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\%~2.pdf
```

Note: use `%~1` to remove surrounding quotes (no effect, if there aren't such)

You might want to check if there *are*  at least two parameters before with:

```
if "%~2"=="" (echo you need two parameters & goto :eof )
```

(Maybe even add some plausibility tests)

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE - It worked in the batch file only with a tilde ( %~1 and %~2) as @compo suggested in my original post comments

Comment: The `~` is to remove surrounding quotes. You didn't mention quotes in your question.