# How to make a list of arguments which is dropped on a batch file?

Tags: list, file, batch-file

I'm trying to create a list of all of the files that are dragged and dropped onto a script, separated by semicolons.

```
set b =
FOR %%a IN (%*) do (
    set "b=%b%%%a;"
) > test.tmp
echo b
pause
```

This is what I have so far, but the script is not displaying the list of files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `set b =` sets a variable named `b` + _space_. Anyway, the problem is lack of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) in the loop; then you are missing the `%`-signs when reading a variable in `echo %b%`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `echo` the full paths and filename of the files you are to drag/drop, without double quotes:

```
@echo off
(for %%a in (%*) do (
   echo %%~a;
  )
)> test.tmp
type test.tmp
pause
```

To include double quotes and full path:

```
@echo off
(for %%a in (%*) do (
   echo %%a;
  )
)> test.tmp
type test.tmp
pause
```

to echo filename only, without path:

```
@echo off
(for %%a in (%*) do (
   echo %%~nxa;
  )
)> test.tmp
type test.tmp
pause
```

and to `echo` filename only, excluding path or extension:

```
@echo off
(for %%a in (%*) do (
   echo %%~na;
  )
)> test.tmp
type test.tmp
pause
```

`type test.tmp` is just to show you the content of the file after written, you can remove it if you do not need it.

I suggest you also read the help for `for` command:

- `for /?`

Lastly, if you really want to set a variable (though not needed) you need to `enabldelayedexpansion` or `call echo %%b%%` by doubling the `%`

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/get-list-of-passed-arguments-in-windows-batch-script-bat) :

sample code in the file `F:\printArguments.bat` may be like that:

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) do (
    CALL:PrintTheArgument %%a
)
pause
GOTO:EOF

:PrintTheArgument

echo. %~1

GOTO:EOF
```

You can test it for example like that:

```
F:\printArguments.bat "edek" "z" "fabryki" "kredek"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "b="

for %%a in (%*) do (
    set "b=!b!%%a;"
)

if defined b (
    > test.tmp echo(!b:~0,-1!
)

pause
```

To append to `b` in the `for` loop, delayed expansion may be needed.
Use `!` instead of `%` for delayed expansioned varaibles.
To trim the trailing `;`, first check if the variable is defined, then
trim the last character by using `-1` in `!b:~0,-1!`, which gets all
characters from position zero to the 2nd last character.

Note: `set b =` is variable name of `b` with a space.

View `set /?` about how to get substrings from strings.